# Variable number of arguments in C++?

Tags: c++, variadic-functions

How can I write a function that accepts a variable number of arguments? Is this possible, how?

Comment: At this time with _C++11_ the answers for this question would greatly differ

Comment: @K-ballo I added C++11 examples as well since a recent question asked this same thing recently and I felt this needed one in order to justify closing it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16337459/undefined-number-of-arguments-in-c#16337614

Comment: Added pre *C++11* options to my answer as well, so it now should cover most of the choices available.

Comment: @K-ballo there is afaik no way to do it in C++ in case you need forced argument type.. no construction like foo(int ... values) :/ If you don't care about types, then yes, variadic templates in C++11 works great

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29326784/4361073

Comment: @nunos: I've just now seen [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58986072) closed as duplicate of this one... please consider shifting the checkmark from wilhelmtell's "this is how it's done in C but it is not good" answer to Shafik's actually-C++ answer.

Comment: @nunos: Is there any particular *reason* why you don't want to change the accepted answer?

Comment: @nunos Can you please change the accepted answer to [the one that covers both the antique solution and the newer C++11 version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16338804)?

Comment: In my case, these five lines were enough: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1056423/1396334 (being this one the most important: `vsnprintf (buffer, 255, format, args);`)

Answer (score 190, accepted):

You probably shouldn't, and you can probably do what you want to do in a safer  and simpler way.  Technically to use variable number of arguments in C you include stdarg.h.  From that you'll get the `va_list` type as well as three functions that operate on it called `va_start()`, `va_arg()` and `va_end()`.

```
#include<stdarg.h>

int maxof(int n_args, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, n_args);
    int max = va_arg(ap, int);
    for(int i = 2; i <= n_args; i++) {
        int a = va_arg(ap, int);
        if(a > max) max = a;
    }
    va_end(ap);
    return max;
}
```

If you ask me, this is a mess.  It looks bad, it's unsafe, and it's full of technical details that have nothing to do with what you're conceptually trying to achieve.  Instead, consider using overloading or inheritance/polymorphism, builder pattern (as in `operator<<()` in streams) or default arguments etc.  These are all safer:  the compiler gets to know more about what you're trying to do so there are more occasions it can stop you before you blow your leg off.

Comment: Presumably, you cannot pass references to a varargs function because the compiler wouldn't know when to pass by value and when by reference, and because the underlying C macros would not necessarily know what to do with references -- there are already restrictions on what you can pass into a C function with variable arguments because of things like promotion rules.

Comment: @Jonathan: That doesn't really matter. The problem is quite solvable in theory, so ISO WG21 can just say: "This is the spec, now you make it work.". There's no good reason why the C++ compiler makers would have to restrict themselves to C macros. For instance, a trivial solution would be to push RTTI information on the stack before each vararg argument. But as wilhemtell correctly explains, even if the compiler could, you'd still have that nasty interface.

Comment: is it necessary to provide atleast one argument before the `...` syntax?

Comment: @Lazer it is not a language or library requirement, but the standard library doesn't give you means to tell the length of the list. You need the caller to give you this information or else somehow figure it out yourself. In the case of `printf()`, for example, the function parses the string argument for special tokens to figure out how many extra arguments it should expect in the variable argument list.

Comment: you should probably use `<cstdarg>` in C++ instead of `<stdarg.h>`

Comment: There does need to be at least one normal parameter before `...`, whose name you pass to `va_start`. This is to allow for implementations where the macro uses the address of that parameter to figure out the addresses of the rest of them (other implementations might for example use some compiler builtin to access the stack or frame pointer).

Comment: I was thinking of using varargs to implement a max(int,int,int..) function. What would be an alternate (and neat) way to do it?

Comment: Variable number of arguments is great for debug or for functions/methods that fill some array. Also it's great for many mathematical operations, such as max, min, sum, average... It's not mess when you don't mess with it.

Comment: @Rushil: Why not implement a max that takes an array of int?

Comment: @MyUsername112358 array would not be a good choice for me as I won't be able to create and pass the array dynamically.

Comment: @Rushil For a max function you should definitely use a vararg template.

Comment: Lack of verbosity is more important than unsafety, imo, so why couch the correct answer in the opinion? just bounced off the initializer list implementation because it introduced too much semantic complexity and verbosity in what should be the same convenient, albeit unsafe, interface that the entry point to main is anyway!

Comment: Anyways, technical details are why we get paid.  There are plenty of technical details to computing an effective numerical derivative, integration, or setting up the PDEs for a nuclear fusion simulation in a tokamak.  The noise at the function interface is the bottleneck for advanced users, not the noise inside the function capsule.  This answer is far and away superior to the ones below.

Answer (score 491):

In *C++11* you have two new options, as the [Variadic arguments](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments) reference page in the *Alternatives section* states:

> - Variadic templates can also be used to create functions that take variable number of
>   arguments. They are often the better choice because they do not impose restrictions on
>   the types of the arguments, do not perform integral and floating-point promotions, and
>   are type safe. (since C++11)
> - If all variable arguments share a common type, a std::initializer_list provides a
>   convenient mechanism (albeit with a different syntax) for accessing variable arguments.

Below is an example showing both alternatives (*[see it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/84c7739d7d7e03cc)*):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <initializer_list>

template <typename T>
void func(T t) 
{
    std::cout << t << std::endl ;
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
void func(T t, Args... args) // recursive variadic function
{
    std::cout << t <<std::endl ;

    func(args...) ;
}

template <class T>
void func2( std::initializer_list<T> list )
{
    for( auto elem : list )
    {
        std::cout << elem << std::endl ;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::string
        str1( "Hello" ),
        str2( "world" );

    func(1,2.5,'a',str1);

    func2( {10, 20, 30, 40 }) ;
    func2( {str1, str2 } ) ;
}
```

If you are using `gcc` or `clang` we can use the [__PRETTY_FUNCTION__ *magic variable*](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Names.html) to display the type signature of the function which can be helpful in understanding what is going on. For example using:

```
std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ": " << t <<std::endl ;
```

would results int following for variadic functions in the example (*[see it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/99bdcbc93e48c922)*):

```
void func(T, Args...) [T = int, Args = <double, char, std::basic_string<char>>]: 1
void func(T, Args...) [T = double, Args = <char, std::basic_string<char>>]: 2.5
void func(T, Args...) [T = char, Args = <std::basic_string<char>>]: a
void func(T) [T = std::basic_string<char>]: Hello
```

In Visual Studio you can use [__FUNCSIG__](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx).

**Update Pre C++11**

Pre *C++11* the alternative for [std::initializer_list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) would be [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or one of the other [standard containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

template <class T>
void func1( std::vector<T> vec )
{
    for( typename std::vector<T>::iterator iter = vec.begin();  iter != vec.end(); ++iter )
    {
        std::cout << *iter << std::endl ;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int arr1[] = {10, 20, 30, 40} ;
    std::string arr2[] = { "hello", "world" } ; 
    std::vector<int> v1( arr1, arr1+4 ) ;
    std::vector<std::string> v2( arr2, arr2+2 ) ;

    func1( v1 ) ;
    func1( v2 ) ;
}
```

and the alternative for *variadic templates* would be [variadic functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic) although they are not *type-safe* and in general [error prone and can be unsafe to use](https://web.archive.org/web/20150501110243/http://robertseacord.sys-con.com/node/158825/mobile) but the only other potential alternative would be to use *default arguments*, although that has limited use. The example below is a modified version of the sample code in the linked reference:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdarg>
 
void simple_printf(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
 
    while (*fmt != '\0') {
        if (*fmt == 'd') {
            int i = va_arg(args, int);
            std::cout << i << '\n';
        } else if (*fmt == 's') {
            char * s = va_arg(args, char*);
            std::cout << s << '\n';
        }
        ++fmt;
    }
 
    va_end(args);
}
 

int main()
{
    std::string
        str1( "Hello" ),
        str2( "world" );

    simple_printf("dddd", 10, 20, 30, 40 );
    simple_printf("ss", str1.c_str(), str2.c_str() ); 

    return 0 ;
}
```

Using *variadic functions* also comes with restrictions in the arguments you can pass which is detailed in the [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/Jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1804.pdf) in section `5.2.2` *Function call* paragraph *7*:

> When there is no parameter for a given argument, the argument is passed in such a way that the receiving function can obtain the value of the argument by invoking va_arg (18.7). The lvalue-to-rvalue (4.1), array-to-pointer (4.2), and function-to-pointer (4.3) standard conversions are performed on the argument expression. After these conversions, if the argument does not have arithmetic, enumeration, pointer, pointer to member, or class type, the program is ill-formed. If the argument has a non-POD class type (clause 9), the behavior is undefined. [...]

Comment: Is your `typename` vs `class` usage above intentional?  If so, please explain.

Comment: @kevinarpe not intentional, it does not change anything though.

Comment: Your first link should probably be to  probably be to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments instead.

Comment: is it possible to make a function taking a `initializer_list` recursive?

Comment: The "error prone and can be unsafe to use" link is broken :-( Archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20150501110243/http://robertseacord.sys-con.com/node/158825/mobile Fixed it.

Answer (score 83):

## A C++17 solution: full type safety + nice calling syntax

Since the introduction of variadic templates in C++11 and fold expressions in C++17, it is possible to define a template-function which, at the caller site, is callable as if it was a varidic function but with the advantages to:

- be strongly type safe;
- work without the run-time information of the number of arguments, or without the usage of a "stop" argument.

Here is an example for mixed argument types

```
template<class... Args>
void print(Args... args)
{
    (std::cout << ... << args) << "\n";
}
print(1, ':', " Hello", ',', " ", "World!");
```

And another with enforced type match for all arguments:

```
#include <type_traits> // enable_if, conjuction

template<class Head, class... Tail>
using are_same = std::conjunction<std::is_same<Head, Tail>...>;

template<class Head, class... Tail, class = std::enable_if_t<are_same<Head, Tail...>::value, void>>
void print_same_type(Head head, Tail... tail)
{
    std::cout << head;
    (std::cout << ... << tail) << "\n";
}
print_same_type("2: ", "Hello, ", "World!");   // OK
print_same_type(3, ": ", "Hello, ", "World!"); // no matching function for call to 'print_same_type(int, const char [3], const char [8], const char [7])'
                                               // print_same_type(3, ": ", "Hello, ", "World!");
                                                                                              ^
```

More information:

1. Variadic templates, also known as parameter pack [*Parameter pack(since C++11) - cppreference.com*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack).
2. Fold expressions [*fold expression(since C++17) - cppreference.com*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold).
3. See a [full program demonstration](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c4bfee842544e957) on coliru.

Comment: one day ill hope i can read `template<class Head, class... Tail, class = std::enable_if_t<are_same<Head, Tail...>::value, void>>`

Comment: @Eladian read it as "This thing is enabled only if `Head` and `Tail...` _are the same_", where "_are the same_" means `std::conjunction<std::is_same<Head, Tail>...>`. Read this last definitinon as "`Head` is the same as all of `Tail...`".

Comment: Can we loop over `args`?

Comment: @AbbasEbadian Yes, but that's a question on its own.

Answer (score 27):

in c++11 you can do:

```
void foo(const std::list<std::string> & myArguments) {
   //do whatever you want, with all the convenience of lists
}

foo({"arg1","arg2"});
```

list initializer FTW!

Comment: Arguments can be general types (Int,Char,Float etc) this doesn't work for them.

Answer (score 23):

In C++11 there is a way to do variable argument templates which lead to a really elegant and type safe way to have variable argument functions.  Bjarne himself gives a nice example of [printf using variable argument templates](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#variadic-templates) in the [C++11FAQ](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html).

Personally, I consider this so elegant that I wouldn't even bother with a variable argument function in C++ until that compiler has support for C++11 variable argument templates.

Comment: @donlan - If you're using C++17, you can use fold expressions to make things a lot simpler in some cases (think creatively here, you can use the `,` operator with fold expressions). Otherwise, I don't think so.

Comment: Nice article referenced.. When I started reading the class template tuple in the section "We can build a variadic type" I suddenly thought: "OMG! This is Lisp programming, at compile time, in C++.."  ..LOL..

Answer (score 15):

C-style variadic functions are supported in C++.

However, most C++ libraries use an alternative idiom e.g. whereas the `'c' printf` function takes variable arguments the `c++ cout` object uses `<<` overloading which addresses type safety and ADTs (perhaps at the cost of implementation simplicity).

Comment: Also, this only seems to work in the case of a function like printing, where you actually have an iteration of a single argument function across each arg.  Otherwise, you are just initializing a list and passing the list for the end around on `std::initializer_lists`... And this is already introducing massive complexity on a simple task.

Answer (score 14):

Apart from varargs or overloading, you could consider to aggregate your arguments in a std::vector or other containers (std::map for example). Something like this:

```
template <typename T> void f(std::vector<T> const&);
std::vector<int> my_args;
my_args.push_back(1);
my_args.push_back(2);
f(my_args);
```

In this way you would gain type safety and the logical meaning of these variadic arguments would be apparent.

Surely this approach can have performance issues but you should not worry about them unless you are sure that you cannot pay the price. It is a sort of a a "Pythonic" approach to c++ ...

Comment: Cleaner would be to not enforce vectors. Instead use a template argument specifying the STL-styled collection then iterate through it using the argument's begin and end methods. This way you can use std::vector<T>, c++11's std::array<T, N>, std::initializer_list<T> or even make your own collection.

Comment: @JensÅkerblom I agree but this is the kind of choice that should be analyzed for the issue at hand, to avoid over engineering. Since this is a matter of API signature, it is important to understand the tradeoff between maximum flexibility and clarity of intent/usability/maintanability etc.

Answer (score 8):

The only way is through the use of C style variable arguments, as described [here](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter9/stdarg.html). Note that this is not a recommended practice, as it's not typesafe and error-prone.

Comment: By error prone I assume you mean potentially very very dangerous? Especially when working with untrusted input.

Comment: Yes, but because of the type safety issues. Think all of the possible issues that regular printf has: format strings not matching passed arguments, and such. printf uses the same technique, BTW.

Answer (score 8):

Using variadic templates, example to reproduce `console.log` as seen in JavaScript:

```
Console console;
console.log("bunch", "of", "arguments");
console.warn("or some numbers:", 1, 2, 3);
console.error("just a prank", "bro");
```

Filename e.g. `js_console.h`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

class Console {
protected:
    template <typename T>
    void log_argument(T t) {
        std::cout << t << " ";
    }
public:
    template <typename... Args>
    void log(Args&&... args) {
        int dummy[] = { 0, ((void) log_argument(std::forward<Args>(args)),0)... };
        cout << endl;
    }

    template <typename... Args>
    void warn(Args&&... args) {
        cout << "WARNING: ";
        int dummy[] = { 0, ((void) log_argument(std::forward<Args>(args)),0)... };
        cout << endl;
    }

    template <typename... Args>
    void error(Args&&... args) {
        cout << "ERROR: ";
        int dummy[] = { 0, ((void) log_argument(std::forward<Args>(args)),0)... };
        cout << endl;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 7):

There is no standard C++ way to do this without resorting to C-style varargs (`...`).

There are of course default arguments that sort of "look" like variable number of arguments depending on the context:

```
void myfunc( int i = 0, int j = 1, int k = 2 );

// other code...

myfunc();
myfunc( 2 );
myfunc( 2, 1 );
myfunc( 2, 1, 0 );
```

All four function calls call `myfunc` with varying number of arguments. If none are given, the default arguments are used. Note however, that you can only omit trailing arguments. There is no way, for example to omit `i` and give only `j`.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible you want overloading or default parameters - define the same function with defaulted parameters:

```
void doStuff( int a, double termstator = 1.0, bool useFlag = true )
{
   // stuff
}

void doStuff( double std_termstator )
{
   // assume the user always wants '1' for the a param
   return doStuff( 1, std_termstator );
}
```

This will allow you to call the method with one of four different calls:

```
doStuff( 1 );
doStuff( 2, 2.5 );
doStuff( 1, 1.0, false );
doStuff( 6.72 );
```

...  or you could be looking for the v_args calling conventions from C.

Answer (score 3):

## C++ 11 with color code support

- Is generic and works for all dataypes
- Works like JavaScript `console.log(1,"23")`
- Supports color codes for info, warning, error.
- Example: 
  [image]

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

const std::string RED = "\e[0;91m";
const std::string BLUE = "\e[0;96m";
const std::string YELLOW = "\e[0;93m";

class Logger {
private:
  enum class Severity { INFO, WARN, ERROR };

  static void print_colored(const char *log, Severity severity) {
    const char *color_code = nullptr;

    switch (severity) {
    case Severity::INFO:
      color_code = BLUE.c_str();
      break;
    case Severity::WARN:
      color_code = YELLOW.c_str();
      break;
    case Severity::ERROR:
      color_code = RED.c_str();
      break;
    }

    std::cout << "\033" << color_code << log << "\033[0m -- ";
  }

  template <class Args> static void print_args(Args args) {
    std::cout << args << " ";
  }

public:
  template <class... Args> static void info(Args &&...args) {
    print_colored("[INFO] ", Severity::INFO);
    int dummy[] = {0, ((void)print_args(std::forward<Args>(args)), 0)...};
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }

  template <class... Args> static void warn(Args &&...args) {
    print_colored("[WARN] ", Severity::WARN);
    int dummy[] = {0, ((void)print_args(std::forward<Args>(args)), 0)...};
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }

  template <class... Args> static void error(Args &&...args) {
    print_colored("[ERROR]", Severity::ERROR);
    int dummy[] = {0, ((void)print_args(std::forward<Args>(args)), 0)...};
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, C-style varargs. But you can also do something similar with default arguments.

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: @QPaysTaxes: For an example of how to do it with default arguments, look at Zoltan's answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
// spawn: allocate and initialize (a simple function)
template<typename T>
T * spawn(size_t n, ...){
  T * arr = new T[n];
  va_list ap;
  va_start(ap, n);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    T[i] = va_arg(ap,T);
  return arr;
}
```

User writes:

```
auto arr = spawn<float> (3, 0.1,0.2,0.3);
```

Semantically, this looks and feels exactly like an n-argument function.  Under the hood, you might unpack it one way or the other.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible now...using boost any and templates
In this case, arguments type can be mixed

```
#include <boost/any.hpp>
#include <iostream>

#include <vector>
using boost::any_cast;

template <typename T, typename... Types> 
void Alert(T var1,Types... var2) 
{ 

    std::vector<boost::any> a(  {var1,var2...});

    for (int i = 0; i < a.size();i++)
    {

    if (a[i].type() == typeid(int))
    {
        std::cout << "int "  << boost::any_cast<int> (a[i]) << std::endl;
    }
    if (a[i].type() == typeid(double))
    {
        std::cout << "double "  << boost::any_cast<double> (a[i]) << std::endl;
    }
    if (a[i].type() == typeid(const char*))
    {
        std::cout << "char* " << boost::any_cast<const char*> (a[i]) <<std::endl;
    }
    // etc
    }

} 


void main()
{
    Alert("something",0,0,0.3);
}
```

Comment: Why add an extra dependency? C++17 gives us a nice class `std::any`.

Answer (score -1):

We could also use an initializer_list if all arguments are const and of the same type

Answer (score -2):

```
int fun(int n_args, ...) {
   int *p = &n_args; 
   int s = sizeof(int);
   p += s + s - 1;
   for(int i = 0; i < n_args; i++) {
     printf("A1 %d!\n", *p);
     p += 2;
   }
}
```

Plain version

Comment: And undefined behavior that won't work on anything other than x86.

Comment: Writing assembly is even better than this.