# NULL definition problem on 64 bit system

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, 64-bit, null

I'm running on RHEL 5.1 64 bit platfrom using gcc 4.1.2.

I have a utility function:

```
void str_concat(char *buff, int buffSize, ...);
```

which concats char * passed in variadic list(...), while last argument should be NULL, to designate end of the arguments. On 64 bit system NULL is 8 bytes.

Now to the problem. My application includes directly/indirectly 2 stddef.h files.

First one is **/usr/include/linux/stddef.h** which defines NULL as following:

```
#undef NULL
#if defined(__cplusplus)
#define NULL 0
#else
#define NULL ((void *)0)
#endif
```

The second one is **/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/include/stddef.h**

```
#if defined (_STDDEF_H) || defined (__need_NULL)
#undef NULL     /* in case <stdio.h> has defined it. */
#ifdef __GNUG__
#define NULL __null
#else   /* G++ */
#ifndef __cplusplus
#define NULL ((void *)0)
#else   /* C++ */
#define NULL 0
#endif  /* C++ */
#endif  /* G++ */
#endif  /* NULL not defined and <stddef.h> or need NULL.  */
#undef  __need_NULL
```

Of course I need the 2nd one, since it defines NULL as __null (8 bytes), while 1st one defines it as integer 0 (4 bytes).

How do I prevent /usr/include/linux/stddef.h to be inderectly included?

UPD:

1. Compilation line is pretty straightforward:

   g++ -Wall -fmessage-length=0 -g -pthread
2. Many of you advised to pass (void *)0. This of course will work. The problem that the function is used in many, I mean many places. I'd like to find solution that will give me what C++ standard promises - NULL of 8 byte size.

Comment: It would help if we had your compilation line, to see the directories in the include path.

Comment: Is it possible to see the assembly output generated ?

Comment: I preprocess file (gcc -E) to proved that NULL is replaces by 0.

Comment: Can you compile with -S and look at the generated source code ?

Comment: Why you need assembly. I see that preprocessor replaces NULL with 0, and sizeof(0) yields 8. So what more you'll see in assembly? ;)

Comment: Because in sizeof(0), 0 is treated as the default integral type int. But if you say char *ptr = 0, then it is promoted to 8 bytes...

Comment: "what C++ standard promises - NULL of 8 byte size". No it very much does not promise any such thing. Not anywhere near.

Comment: @idimba: Your update just doesn't make any sense. C++ standard never promiced anything aboout the actual size of `NULL`. You must be confusing it with something else.

Comment: The standard actually says: The macro NULL is an implementation defined C++ null pointer constant in this International Standard
(4.10). (with footnote 180, which says: Possible definitions include 0 and 0L, but not (void*)0.)

Comment: @Malkocoglu: Not only it is absolutely useless to "look at the assembly output" in this case, but your analysis of the assembly output is incorrect.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's no "NULL definiton problem" in this case. There's a problem with how you are trying to use `NULL` in your code.

`NULL` cannot be portably passed to variadic functions in C/C++ by itself. You have to explicitly cast it before passing, i.e. in your case you have to pass `(const char*) NULL` as the terminator of the argument list.

Your question is tagged as C++. In any case, regardless of size, in C++ `NULL` will always be defined as an *integer* constant. It is illegal in C++ to define `NULL` as a pointer. Since your function expects a pointer (`const char *`), no definition of `NULL` will ever work for it in C++ code.

For cleaner code you can define your own constant, like

```
const char* const STR_TERM = NULL;
```

and use it in the calls to your function. But you will never be able to meaningfully use just `NULL` for that purpose. Whenever a plain `NULL` is passed as a variadic argument, it is a blatant portability bug that has to be fixed.

**Added:** your update claims that "C++ standard promises `NULL` of 8 byte size" (on a 64-bit platform I presume). This just doesn't make any sense. C++ standard does not promise anything like that about `NULL`.

`NULL` is intended to be used as an rvalue. It has no specific size and there's no valid use of `NULL` where its actual size might even remotely matter.

---

Quoting from ISO/IEC 14882:1998, section 18.1 'Types', paragraph 4:

> The macro NULL is an implementation defined
>   C++ null pointer constant in this International Standard
>   (4.10).<sup>180)</sup>
>
> <sup>180)</sup> Possible definitions include 0 and 0L, but not (void*)0.

Comment: Perfectly acceptable to pass a non-const null pointer - and shorter.

Comment: "NULL cannot be portably passed to variadic functions in C/C++ by itself." - No, it can't be done in C++. I'm pretty sure it's fine in C.

Comment: @Chris Lutz: No, it is not fine in C. How could you know whether you are passing `0`, `0L`, `(void *) 0` or something else?

Answer (score 5):

One solution - possibly even the best, but certainly very reliable - is to pass an explicit null char pointer to your function calls:

```
str_concat(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "str1", "str2", ..., (char *)0);
```

or:

```
str_concat(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "str1", "str2", ..., (char *)NULL);
```

This is standard recommended practice for the `execl()` function in POSIX systems, for example, and for precisely the same reason - the trailing arguments of a variable-length argument list are subject to usual promotions (char or short to int; float to double), but cannot otherwise be type safe.

It is also why C++ practitioners generally avoid [variable-length argument lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657883/variable-number-of-arguments-in-c); they are not type safe.

Answer (score 3):

Removing the `__GNUG__`case, and inverting the ifdef/endif in the second file, BOTH files do:

```
#undef NULL
#if defined(__cplusplus)
#define NULL 0
#else
#define NULL ((void *)0)
#endif
```

Which is to say that they define NULL as ((void *)0) for C compilations and 0 for C++.

So the simple answer is "Don't compile as C++".

Your real problem is your desire to use NULL in your variadic arugment list, combined with your compiler's unpredictable argument sizing.  What you MIGHT try is writing "(void *)0" instead of NULL to terminate your list, and force the compiler pass an 8-byte pointer instead of a 4-byte int.

Comment: Since it is a list of 'const char *' values that is passed, it seems logical to use '(char *)0' rather than '(void *)0', though I agree the end result is indistinguishable.

Answer (score 1):

You may not be able to fix the includes because system includes are a twisty maze.

You might fix the problem by using (void*)0 or (char*)0 instead of NULL.

After considering it I am rejecting my previous idea of redefining NULL. That would be a bad thing to do and could mess up a lot of other code.

Comment: Redefining NULL leads to madness greater than that which caused the question to be asked.

Answer (score 0):

I previously replied with the below answer. But then I saw that I misinterpreted several information and gave an incorrect answer. Just out of curiosity, I did the same test with VS2008 and I got different results. This is just brain exercise...

```
Why do you need the second one ? Both headers say the same thing.
And it does not even matter if you write 0 or NULL or ((void *)0)
All of them will take 8 bytes.
```

I did a quick test on a 64-bit platform with GCC 4.1.3

```
#include <string.h>

void str_concat(char *po_buf, int pi_max, ...)
{
    strcpy(po_buf, "Malkocoglu"); /* bogus */
}

int main()
{
    char buf[100];
    str_concat(buf, 100, "abc", 1234LL, "def", 5678LL, "ghi", 2345LL, "jkl", 6789LL, "mno", 3456LL, 0, "pqx", 0);
    return 1;
}
```

And this is the assembly generated by the compiler...

```
main:
.LFB3:
    pushq   %rbp
.LCFI3:
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
.LCFI4:
    subq    $192, %rsp
.LCFI5:
    leaq    -112(%rbp), %rdi
    movl    $0, 64(%rsp)                          0
    movq    $.LC2, 56(%rsp)                       "pqx"
    movl    $0, 48(%rsp)                          0
    movq    $3456, 40(%rsp)                       3456LL
    movq    $.LC3, 32(%rsp)                       "mno"
    movq    $6789, 24(%rsp)                       6789LL
    movq    $.LC4, 16(%rsp)                       "jkl"
    movq    $2345, 8(%rsp)                        2345LL
    movq    $.LC5, (%rsp)                         "ghi"
    movl    $5678, %r9d                           5678LL
    movl    $.LC0, %r8d                           "def"
    movl    $1234, %ecx                           1234LL
    movl    $.LC1, %edx                           "abc"
    movl    $100, %esi                            100
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    str_concat
    movl    $1, %eax
    leave
    ret
```

Notice all the stack displacements are 8 byte...

```
Compiler treats 0 as it was a 32-bit data-type.
Although it does the correct displacement on the
stack pointer, the value pushed should not be 32-bit !
```

I did the same test with VS2008 , the assembly output is as follows :

```
mov QWORD PTR [rsp+112], 0
lea rax, OFFSET FLAT:$SG3597
mov QWORD PTR [rsp+104], rax
mov QWORD PTR [rsp+96], 0
mov QWORD PTR [rsp+88], 3456        ; 00000d80H
lea rax, OFFSET FLAT:$SG3598
mov QWORD PTR [rsp+80], rax
mov QWORD PTR [rsp+72], 6789        ; 00001a85H
lea rax, OFFSET FLAT:$SG3599
mov QWORD PTR [rsp+64], rax
mov QWORD PTR [rsp+56], 2345        ; 00000929H
lea rax, OFFSET FLAT:$SG3600
mov QWORD PTR [rsp+48], rax
mov QWORD PTR [rsp+40], 5678        ; 0000162eH
lea rax, OFFSET FLAT:$SG3601
mov QWORD PTR [rsp+32], rax
mov r9d, 1234               ; 000004d2H
lea r8, OFFSET FLAT:$SG3602
mov edx, 100                ; 00000064H
lea rcx, QWORD PTR buf$[rsp]
call    ?str_concat@@YAXPEADHZZ         ; str_concat
```

This time compiler generates different code and it treats 0 as an 64-bit data-type (notice the QWORD keyword). Both the value and stack displacement is correct. VS and GCC behaves differently.

Comment: Actually I just perked up, is `int` 4 bytes on a 64-bits platform right ?

Comment: It depends on system/compiler/ABI but yes generally int is 4 bytes but 0 is not. 0 is a number, it is not a type (like int/long/char) and it is promoted to whatever compiler thinks it should be...

Comment: Downvoted because 0 is *not* 8 bytes. I ran into this with some Gnome software in the very early days of Gentoo AMD64. In a variadic argument list, C does not know to convert 0 to a pointer so you must cast to void*.

Comment: constant 0 on 64 system is 4 bytes. Just try to print sizeof(0) and sizeof(NULL) and you'll see. And in my case the size do matters, since I pass NULL on the stack

Comment: @Zan Lynx - the function str_concate is used in heavily used in application and I would happy with solution where I can NULL, which is promised by C++ by a null pointer of size 8 byte.

Comment: In the AMD64 ABI it says, "INTEGER This class consists of integral types that ﬁt into one of the general purpose registers.". As the general purpose register is 64-bit wide, 0 is promoted to 64-bit. What GCC version is this ?

Comment: gcc 4.1.2 (see 1st line of the question)

Comment: Neither C nor C++ make an absolute requirement, but the "spirit" of both standards would be that `sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT==64` on a 64-bit system. Problem is, neither provided a `short short` so compiler vendors don't have reasonable names for 32 and 16 bits types, but they have plenty of names for types bigger than `int`. As a result `int` ends up as 32 bits. Note that NULL may also be defined as `0ULL` in which case its type _would_ be 64 bits on those systems.

Comment: @Malkocoglu: Not only it is absolutely useless to "look at the assembly output" in this case, but your analysis of the output is incorrect. Displacements in stack do not matter. What matters is that your `0` are placed into the stack by a `movl`. `movl` is a 4-byte copy, not 8 (`movq` would copy 8), meaning that compiler treats your 0's as an ordinary 4-byte `int`, as it should. I.e. your compiler reserves 8-bytes for each argument, but initializes only as much as really necessary (4 in case of `0`'). If you interpret this argument as 8-byte pointer, you'll get garbage in high-order bytes.

Comment: @AndreyT: http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/assembly.html look at the section named Implicit zero extend...

Comment: @Malkocoglu: You are pretty lost. "Zero extension" is completely irrelevant here. There's no such thing as "implicit zero extension" when writing into *memory*. It only works with registers. The calling code puts exactly 4 bytes into memory and only 4 bytes will be initialized. The upper 4 bytes will be garbage. The function code will think that it need to read 8 bytes, and it will read all 8, including garbage. No "zero extension" in that case as well.

Comment: @Malkocoglu: ... And all that on top of the fact that looking into some specific assembly output demonstrates absolutely nothing relevant to the original question, even if some particlar compiler somehow happened to generate some particular code that would somehow manage to work in this case.

Comment: No, MSVC does not treat `0` as a 64-bit datatype, which you can easily verify by looking at the result of `sizeof(0)`. What you see in the disassembly is just that MSVC decided to clean-up the garbage that would be left in 8-byte emory word after placing a 4-byte `0` into it. It just felt like it. This means that the code might actually "work" on MSVC just because of that charitable behavior of MSVC. Nevertheless, it does make the code even remotely correct.

Comment: Okey, I accept; it is incorrect. But does not "It just felt like it" translate to Windows ABI ? I could not find a solid reference but maybe Windows (VS) ABI mandates that if it does not know the type, it treats it as 64-bit. Because of what it says here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235286.aspx