# va_arg with a list of void*

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I would like to create a function that takes a variable number of void pointers,

```
val=va_arg(vl,void*);
```

but above doesn't work, is there portable way to achieve this using some other type instead of void*?

Comment: -1 for describing a problem with "doesn't work".

Comment: Works OK for me. Can you post the rest of the code that uses the va_list? Or error messages? Which compiler did you use?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Variable number of arguments in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657883/variable-number-of-arguments-in-c)

Comment: C++? https://dbj.org/c-how-to-simply-handle-variable-number-of-function-arguments/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void
myfunc(void *ptr, ...)
{
    va_list va;
    void *p;

    va_start(va, ptr);
    for (p = ptr; p != NULL; p = va_arg(va, void *)) {
        printf("%p\n", p);
    }
    va_end(va);
}

int
main() {
    myfunc(main,
           myfunc,
           printf,
           NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using Fedora 14..

Comment: right, it actually works my bad, its 5 am here should have gotten some sleep before asking.

Comment: That's a bad example call, since function pointers are not convertable to `void *` (that's a GCC extension).

Comment: Sentinel value must be used, in this case, that is `NULL` last argument.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have a C++ tag, I'm going to say "don't do it this way". Instead, either use insertion operators like streams do OR just pass a `(const) std::vector<void*>&` as the only parameter to your function.

Then you don't have to worry about the issues with varargs.