# c++ functions with variable and not known number of arguments

Tags: c++, function

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Variable number of arguments in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657883/variable-number-of-arguments-in-c)

May I not set the number of arguments of a function with variable number of arguments? As an example: can the following interface be implemented?

```
int sum(...) { ... }

sum(1, 2, 3, 4); // return 10
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function

Comment: Shouldn't be hard to set up a variadic template to do this, assuming your compiler supports them. I'd post an answer, but I don't have such a compiler handy to test my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conventional [variadic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function) are messy and not type-safe, but in [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) you can do this cleanly using [variadic templates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template) and (compile-time) recursion:

```
// Base case for recursion
template <typename T>
inline T sum(T n) {
  return n;
}

// Recursive case
template <typename T, typename... Args>
inline T sum(T n, Args... args) {
  return n + sum(args...);
}
```

Since it's a template, this'll work for any types that have an `operator+` defined:

```
std::cout << sum(1, 2, 3) << std::endl;  // Prints 6
std::cout << sum(3.14, 2.72) << std::endl;  // Prints 5.86
```

However, because the return type of the recursive template function is taken from the first argument only, you can get suprising results if you mix different argument types in one call:  `sum(2.5, 2)` returns 4.5 as expected, but `sum(2, 2.5)` returns 2 because the return type is `int`, not `double`.  If you want to be fancy, you can use the new [alternative function syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Alternative_function_syntax) to specify that the return type is whatever the natural type of `n + sum(args...)` would be:

```
// Recursive case
template <typename T, typename... Args>
inline auto sum(T n, Args... args) -> decltype(n + sum(args...)) {
  return n + sum(args...);
}
```

Now `sum(2.5, 2)` and `sum(2, 2.5)` both return 4.5.

If your actual logic is more complex than summation, and you don't want it inlined, you can use the inline template functions to put all the values into some sort of container (such as a `std::vector` or `std::array`) and pass that into the non-inline function to do the real work at the end.

Comment: I'm guessing you're using GCC if you're using variadic templates. The trailing return syntax [works fine on ideone](http://ideone.com/uVS8x)  and also GCC 4.7.1 from http://nuwen.net/mingw.html. If you're interested, it's a great distribution.

Comment: @chris, I'm using GCC 4.7.1, and I know the trailing return syntax works in general.  But using a return type of `decltype(n + sum(args...))` didn't compile — it complained that it couldn't find a matching template.  I tried a few things, but didn't spend a great deal of time on it.

Comment: Ok, I tried that exact code on the end of the recursive `sum` and it worked just fine: `inline auto sum (T n, Args... args) -> decltype (n + sum(args...))`

Comment: Strange, now it works for me too.  I must've had a typo somewhere last time.  Thanks for the sanity check.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to do this by writing the function to take something like a `vector<int>`, which you'll construct on the fly with a braced initializer list:

```
int sum(std::vector<int> const &n) { 
    return std::accumulate(begin(n), end(n), 0);
}
```

If there's some possibility the numbers might be (for example) floating point instead, you probably want to write it as a template instead:

```
template <class T>
T sum(std::vector<T> const &n) { 
   return std::accumulate(begin(n), end(n), T());
}
```

Either way, you'd invoke this just marginally differently:

```
int x = sum({1,2,3,4});
```

Warning: this feature was added to C++ fairly recently, so some compilers (e.g., VC++) don't support it yet -- though others (e.g., g++ 4.7+), do.

Comment: Could also do `template<std::size_t N> int sum(const std::array<int, N>& n) { ... }`

Comment: @DeadMG: Good point -- that may be the best alternative for a compiler that doesn't support C++11.

Comment: @DeadMG: how to call the function?

Comment: @Marshall, `std::array` doesn't overload a constructor to take an initializer list. Instead, you can use `sum<3>({{2, 3, 5}});`

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't.

Just don't use variable arguments. They suck in every conceivable fashion and are completely not worth anybody's time.

Answer (score 0):

A C++ variadic function must know how many (and what type) of arguments it was passed. For example, printf's format string tells it what extra arguments to expect.

Your `sum` has no way of knowing if it got 4 ints or 10. You could make the 1st argument a length:

```
int sum(int howmany, ...) { ... }
```

so the function knows how many ints follow. But really you should just pass an array (or vector if you're feeling C++'y)

Comment: If you're feeling really adventurous you could use wrap the function call in a Boost macro that prepends the number of arguments...

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to solve your issue. I'll go over a few:

Method 1:
-Create a series of overloaded sum functions to suit your needs.

Cons
-code bloat

This can be implemented by making multiple functions with headers:

```
int sum(int a);
int sum(int a, int b);
int sum(int a, int b, int c);
```

etc...

Method 2:
-create a custom class with a linked list, and pass in a pointer to the head of the linked list. This is probably your best move in this case, assuming you don't know the amount of data to be passed in.

Function header:

```
int sum(LinkedList *headPointer);
```

Method 3:
-pass in an array of variables

Function header:

```
int sum(int input[]);
```

Method 4:
-create a function with auto-set variables

Function header:

```
int sum(int a=0, int b=0, int c=0, int d=0,... int n=0);
```

Comment: another one: int sum(int a=0, int b=0, int c=0, int d=0, int e=0) {...}

Comment: Why a custom list class and not a container from the STL?

Comment: good call luskan, this is another method that will auto-set the variables you don't pass in to 0. could work depending on what your funciton does.

Comment: @betabandido Either way will work, i use custom list classes for the learning experience it offers. acts as a good refresher

Comment: @kabirpong Indeed it might be a good idea if you want to refresh how lists are made, but probably not the best idea when giving advice to someone else :)