# formatting string with incrementing integer c++

Tags: c++, printf

Is there a quick way to do the following without the repetition of `i++`

```
int i = 0;
printf("foo-%d,blah-%d,orange-%d", i++, i++, i++);
```

I need to do this with 8 or more pairs and the code looks horrible..

Comment: Not only does it look horrible, it's undefined behavior.

Comment: You've got a whole lot of undefined behavior here.

Comment: Maybe you will need to create you own function in order to keep your code as clean as possible. Take a look at vprintf (http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/vprintf/) and variable arguments functions (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657883/variable-number-of-arguments-in-c)

Comment: One question under both [c++] and [printf] ... wow O_ó ... jsut to sound less obnoxious ... it's plain c, it should not be confused, even though it compiles.

Comment: Why not `printf("foo-1,blah-2,orange-3");` or `int x = ...; printf("foo-%d,blah-%d,orange-%d", x, x + 1, x + 2);`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you can have 8 or more pairs, I would like to suggest you to use a more readably and easy to extend version:

```
std::vector<std::string> vec_values = {"foo", "blah", "orange"};
for (size_t index = 0; index < vec_values.size(); ++index)
    std::cout << vec_values[index] << "-" << index;
```

Answer (score 4):

The order of evaluation of arguments is unspecified. Also, you can't modify a variable twice without an intervening sequence point. So do this instead:

```
printf("foo-%d,blah-%d,orange-%d", i, i+1, i+2);
i+=3;
```

Comment: I didn't know the rule about modifying a variable twice.. thanks. (the order was unimportant).

Comment: Really? You don't care if the output is `foo-1,blah-2,orange-3` or `foo-3,blah-1,orange-2` or `foo-2,blah-3,orange-1` or ...?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz +1 ...The `foo-1,blah-1,orange-1` is also possible :)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Right, because the lack of a sequence point makes this UB, so anything can happen. There are actually two issues here.

Answer (score 1):

You might think of it in terms of the prefixes, not of the number:

```
int i = 0;
std::vector<std::string> prefixes { "foo", "bar", "baz", "ham" };

bool first = false;
for (const auto& prefix : prefixes) {
    if (!first)
        std::cout << ',';
    std::cout << prefix << '-' << i++;
    first = false;
}
```

If you can’t use C++11 range-based `for`, you can write it out in full:

```
for (auto prefix = prefixes.begin(); prefix != prefixes.end(); ++prefix) {
//   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    if (!first)
        std::cout << ',';
    std::cout << *prefix << '-' << i++;
    //           ~~~~~~~
    first = false;
}
```

Alternatively, use indices:

```
for (i = 0; i < prefixes.size(); ++i) {
//   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    if (!first)
        std::cout << ',';
    std::cout << prefixes[i] << '-' << i;
    //           ~~~~~~~~~~~           ~
    first = false;
}
```