# Using Variable Argument List in a Template

Tags: c++, variadic-functions

I have been trying to figure out the problem that I am facing in the following piece of code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class C {
        vector<T> vec;
    public:
        void PrintValues(int size, T val, ...){
            va_list v;
            va_start(v,val);
            for ( int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++ ) {
                T p = va_arg(v,T);
                vec.push_back(p);
                cout<<p<<" ";
            }
            va_end(v);
        }       
};

int main() {
    C<int> a;
    C<char *> b;
    cout<<endl;
    a.PrintValues(10,1,4,6,2,8,5,3,7,10,9);
    cout<<endl;
    b.PrintValues(10,"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j");
    cout<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled this code on my Ubuntu 10.04 desktop using g++ 4.4.3.

The code compiled with the following warning

```
testcode.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
testcode.cpp:25: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’
```

While I was expecting an output like

```
1 4 6 2 8 5 3 7 10 9
a b c d e f g h i j
```

I actually got the following output

```
4 6 2 8 5 3 7 10 9 0
b c d e f g h i j `*@
```

Can someone please provide me with some pointers regarding why the first element in the list is skipped? I know that I can also do the same thing without using the variable argument list, but I am just trying out if this is possible.

Comment: Incidentally, `...` isn’t type safe, don’t use it; use C++11 variable template arguments instead.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: OP doesn't need variadic types, he needs variadic function args of the same type

Comment: @AndyT That’s irrelevant, the same solution applies since C++ doesn’t support same-type, type-safe variadic arguments.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: could you please elaborate? I really don't see how variadic templates can help here. It seems to me that OP tries to implement a convenient way to take arbitrary number of *the same type* args. Something that can be accomplished by initializer list, e.g. `vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3}; do_something(v);`.

Comment: @AndyT OP is using variadic arguments at the moment. Variadic templates do the same, just type safe.

Comment: @KonradRudolph To be fair `std:::initializer_list` could possibly be a better solution since all the types are the same, which is what I added to my answer. BTW, this is also the recommendation here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic as well.

Answer (score 2):

Your first element is being put into the `T val` parameter, and not into `va_list v;`. This is because `va_start(v, val)` sets up `v` with the var-args which start **after** `val`, not **including** val. Have some [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdarg/va_start/)

Comment: Thanks for guiding me in the correct direction. That really helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You are eating the first part of your list in `val` argument and so you actually have one less element in your list than you are indicating with `size`:

```
 void PrintValues(int size, T val, ...)
                            ^^^^^
```

So in the first case `val` will be `1` and the second case `a`. One potential fix would be to drop the `val` arg:

```
void PrintValues(int size, ...)
```

and alter your `va_start`:

```
va_start(v,size);
```

I realize you are just experimenting but this is not type safe and we have [variadic templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657883/variable-number-of-arguments-in-c/16338804#16338804) with C++11 now. Although since you are using only one type std:::initializer_list is also a viable alternative, as mentioned in the previous link.

Comment: sorry but I don't see how variadic templates are applicable here. OP uses variadic number of function args of the same type.

Comment: This really fixed my problem, even though I know it is not type safe. Thanks a lot for the fix.