# Undefined number of arguments in C++

Tags: c++, overloading, variadic-functions

Can I overload my function to do something with a lot of arguments as in *JavaScript*.
For example:

```
function f()
{
  alert(arguments[0]);
}

f(4); // will alert 4
```

Can I do the same thing in *C++* ?

Comment: So you want to call your function with a variable number of arguments? If that is the case you can always use variadic functions but like this page says http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic `std::initializer_list` or `variadic templates` are type safe and easier to use.

Comment: Sorry, my example had an extra colon in it which kept it from compiling correctly. See my new edit please along with the [demo](http://ideone.com/uc3ZE5#view_edit_box).

Answer (score 9):

You can use variadic template arguments and tuples:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

template <class... Args>
void f(Args&&... args)
{
    auto arguments = std::make_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    std::cout << std::get<0>(arguments);
}

void f() {} // for 0 arguments

int main()
{
    f(2, 4, 6, 8);
}
```

[***Live Demo***](http://ideone.com/uc3ZE5#view_edit_box)

For bounds checking, try the following:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

template <class... T>
struct input
{
    std::tuple<T...> var;
    input(T&&... t) : var(std::forward<T>(t)...) {}

    template <std::size_t N, bool in_range = 0 <= N && N < std::tuple_size<decltype(var)>::value>
    auto get() -> typename std::tuple_element<in_range ? N : 0, std::tuple<T...>>::type
    {
        return std::get<in_range ? N : 0>(var);
    }
};

template <class... Args>
void f(Args&&... args)
{
    auto arguments = input<Args...>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);

    std::cout << arguments.template get<9>();
}

void f() {} // for 0 arguments

int main()
{
    f(2, 4, 6, 8);
}
```

---

Update: If you need the first argument then you simply want a function which exposes that first argument by separating it from the parameter pack:

```
template<class Head, class... Tail>
void foo(Head&& head, Tail&&... tail);
```

If this is not satisfactory (i.e you want to get the nth-argument), you can unpack the arguments into a `std::tuple<>` and retrieve an element with `std::get<>`:

```
template<class... Args>
void foo(Args&&... args)
{
    auto t = std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    print(std::get<5>(t));
}
```

Comment: @shafikYaghmour Your question is a little vague. Can you narrow it down to a specific scenario?

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour You'll need to use some form of looping to get all `N` elements. You can use a range-based for to do this: `for (auto a : tup) print( a )`. You can also use compile-time constants through template arguments.

Comment: Is there a way to force args to be a single specific type? (Without having to abuse defaults like so: `template<class T = int, T... args) void f(T&&... args)`)

Comment: @Pharap You can use SFINAE: `template<class T, class...> using first = T; template<class... Args> first<void, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<Args, int>::value>::type...> f(Args&&...);`. [Here's an example.](http://rextester.com/JVF56882)

Comment: Thank you 1234567890, I was unable to find a decent answer for that anywhere. I was probably searching the wrong terms admittedly. SFINAE is truly the answer to all life's mysteries.

Comment: @Pharap Glad I could help. BTW I haven't seen this answer since I wrote it last year and my code is too detailed and superfluous. I am going to update it.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't managed to get what you suggested workingin my compiler (MSVC2013). Removing the ... from the ::type... got rid of any errors, but then it accepts different types of arguments.

Comment: @Pharap What's the error that you were originally getting?

Comment: `error C3546: '...' : there are no parameter packs available to expand` on the line `first<void, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<Args, int>::value>::type...>`. And yes, I made sure to `#include <type_traits>`.

Comment: @Pharap MSVC has incomplete C++11 support. This code runs on other modern compilers. And unfortunately I don't know a work around.

Comment: I suspected as much, it doesn't have support for constexpr yet either. Though as far as I'm aware, no compiler has fully implemented the standard yet, which is a shame since the C++11 features have been a brilliant revolution. If I figure out a work around I'll come back with a comment or edit suggestion. For now I'd better stop flooding the comment box since, I was only asking on the off-chance anyway, I didn't expect to trail off into a long conversation. Thanks for the help though, it's much appreciated.