# Optionally taking a function variable as a parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, parameters, default

I have two functions that do nearly the same thing, the only difference is that one instantiates one of its variables while the other takes it as a parameter:

```
void f1()
{
    myType o;
    // do work on o
}

void f2(shared_ptr<myType> o)
{
    // do work on o
}
```

This is because some callers need o after the work is done, while some others do not. There is a lot of work done, and right now keeping the functions in sync is a copy-paste affair (also changing "o." to "o->"). Is it possible to combine these into a single function, such that if the caller passes in an o, then that is used (as in f2), otherwise one is constructed (as in f1)? Perhaps by setting a default value in the signature?

Comment: Maybe `void f2(shared_ptr<myType> = nullptr)`?

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657883/variable-number-of-arguments-in-c

Comment: @0x499602D2 I get an error, "redefinition of default parameter".

Comment: @fatcat1111 you should only specify the default parameter in the function declaration, **not** the definition. Else you get the error you cite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `std::make_shared` function in conjunction with a default parameter :

```
void f2 (shared_ptr<myType> o = make_shared<myType>())
```

Comment: Could this be generalized to support parameters that require some pointer manipulation, like "f(shared_ptr<myType>& o)"?

Comment: For a reference to have a default parameter, you need a global variable of the same type, i.e. one `shared_ptr<myType> g = std::make_shared<myType>();` in the global scope, and then `void f (std::shared_ptr<int> & o = g)`. What do you want to do, specifically ?

Comment: My concrete aim was met by your answer. I was just thinking through this, trying to wrap my head around defaults.

Answer (score 1):

The first function can forward to the second function by using a `std::shared_ptr` with a *null deleter*:

```
struct null_deleter
{
    template <typename T>
    void operator()(T*) { }
};

void f1()
{
    myType o;
    f2(std::shared_ptr<myType>(&o, null_deleter{}));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply overload the functions:

```
void f1() // void seems odd, wouldn't you return o after you've done work on it?
{
    yourType o;
    // do work on o
}
void f1(yourType& o)
{
    // do work on o
}
```

Comment: I was hoping to have just one function, so that I don't have to duplicate code between f1 and f2 (or f1 & f1). As an aside, the work done in these functions are all side-effects. It's a very non-functional design.

Comment: Call second from first, put all the logic in the function with the argument.