# Can this not be done with variadic template parameter packs?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

In the code below I expand a parameter pack inside an initializer list, while calling a function `DoSomethingReturnInt` on each element. Below that I attempt to do something seemingly similar to try and call `DoSomething` on each element, but get a compiler error. Is this simply not possible or do I simply have to modify it slightly to accomplish this? It seems to me that something like this should be possible.

```c++
template <class T>
int DoSomethingReturnInt(T&& t) 
{}

template <class T>
void DoSomething(T&& t) 
{}

template <class... T>
void variadic(T&&... args) 
{
    int arr[] = { DoSomethingReturnInt(args)... }; //Compiles OK
    DoSomething(args)...; //error: parameter packs not expanded with '...'
}

int main()
{
    variadic("Testing", "one", 2.0, 3);
}
```

Comment: Typically you use recursion to go through the arguments, see my [example here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16338804/1708801).

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour I'm aware that this can be done with recursion and overloading. I thought perhaps there was a simpler way considering how clean the syntax is for expanding `DoSomethingReturnInt(args)...` inside of an initializer list. Am I expecting too much? ;)

Comment: Pack expansion is only allowed in certain contexts; a freestanding statement is not one of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a valid location for parameter pack expansion. The valid contexts for pack expansion is covered in the [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) section `14.5.3` *Variadic templates* which says:

> A pack expansion consists of a pattern and an ellipsis, the
>   instantiation of which produces zero or more instantiations of the
>   pattern in a list (described below). The form of the pattern depends
>   on the context in which the expansion occurs. Pack expansions can
>   occur in the following contexts:
>
> — In a function parameter pack
>   (8.3.5); the pattern is the parameter-declaration without the
>   ellipsis.
>
> — In a template parameter pack that is a pack expansion (14.1):
>
> — if the template parameter pack is a parameter-declaration; the pattern is the parameter-declaration
>   without the ellipsis;
>
> — if the template parameter pack is a type-parameter with a template-parameter-list; the pattern is
>   the corresponding type-parameter without the ellipsis.
>
> — In an initializer-list (8.5); the pattern is an initializer-clause.
>
> — In a base-specifier-list (Clause 10); the pattern is a base-specifier.
>
> — In a mem-initializer-list (12.6.2); the pattern is a mem-initializer.
>
> — In a template-argument-list (14.3); the pattern is a template-argument.
>
> — In a dynamic-exception-specification (15.4); the pattern is a type-id.
>
> — In an attribute-list (7.6.1); the pattern is an attribute.
>
> — In an alignment-specifier (7.6.2); the pattern is the alignment-specifier without the ellipsis.
>
> — In a capture-list (5.1.2); the pattern is a capture.
>
> — In a sizeof... expression (5.3.3); the pattern is an identifier.

This is also covered on cppreference section for [Parameter pack](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack).

Answer (score 4):

You can use the comma operator to your advantage here.

```
int dummy[] = { (DoSomething(args), 0)... };
```

EDIT: If you don't like the comma operator "abuse", maybe a lambda?

```
int dummy[] = { []() { DoSomething(args); return 0; }()... };
```

Note that gcc4.9 doesn't seem to be able to handle this, but clang will do just fine.

Comment: I can't quite decide if this is good idea or not. :)

Comment: @Chris_F as I have argued [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18444099/1708801) there are not many good uses for the comma operator and a lot of ways to abuse it. This looks like an abuse to me.