# How can I write a function in C++ that takes variable number of vectors of double?

Tags: c++, arguments, stdvector, argument-passing, variadic-functions

I am trying to combine different number of `vector<double>` variables into a `vector< vector<double> >`. I try to use `cstdarg` library. It throws out

> error: cannot receive objects of non-trivially-copyable type ‘class myvectortype’ through ‘...’;

where

> typedef vector< double > myvectortype;
>   typedef vector< myvectortype > datavectortype;

Here is the definition of the function

```
datavectortype ExtractData::GetPixelData(int num, ...)
{
        datavectortype data_temp;
        va_list arguments;
        va_start (arguments, num);
        for(int i = 0; i<num; i++)
        {
                data_temp.push_back(va_arg ( arguments, myvectortype));
        }
        va_end ( arguments );
        return data_temp;
}
```

What could be done to fix this, thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Variable number of arguments in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657883/variable-number-of-arguments-in-c)

Comment: @bariskand: If all you are doing is pushing them back into a vector of vectors (you should use `std::move`, by the way) then you don't need a function for this. Just put them in curly braces (i.e. form an `initializer_list`.) Like this: `datavectortype vov = {v0, v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6};`.

Comment: OP, and don't forget to include the header utility if you are to use std::move

Comment: @al-Acme, I am aware of that post, however I could not I understand how to handle  it with vector structure, example with initialize_list is obscure to me.

Comment: Take a vector of vectors of double

Comment: This seems like an XY problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since C++11, you already just could do

```
std::vector<double> v1{1}, v2{2}, v3{3, 4};
std::vector<std::vector<double>> v {v1, v2, v3};
```

But if you want to do a function for that, you may use variadic template:

```
template <typename T, typename ...Ts>
std::vector<T> make_vector(const T& arg, const Ts&... args)
{
    return {arg, args...};
}
```

and so use it like:

```
std::vector<double> v1{1}, v2{2}, v3{3, 4};
std::vector<std::vector<double>> v = make_vector(v1, v2, v3);
```

Comment: I like your answer a lot better :)