# How to make a variadic macro for std::cout?

Tags: c++, c++11, c-preprocessor

How would I make a macro that took a variable amount of arguments, and prints its out using std::cout? Sorry if this is a noob question, couldn't find anything that clarified variadic macros after searching around for the answer.

Conceptual Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#define LOG(...) std::cout << ... << ... << std::endl
int main() {
    LOG("example","output","filler","text");
    return 0;
}
```

would output:

```
exampleoutputfillertext
```

Answer (score 35):

You do not need preprocessor macros to do this. You can write it in ordinary
C++. In C++11/14:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

void log(){}

template<typename First, typename ...Rest>
void log(First && first, Rest && ...rest)
{
    std::cout << std::forward<First>(first);
    log(std::forward<Rest>(rest)...);
}

int main()
{
    log("Hello", "brave","new","world!\n");
    log("1", 2,std::string("3"),4.0,'\n');
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4947b7dede1e8849)

In C++17:

```
template<typename ...Args>
void log(Args && ...args)
{
    (std::cout << ... << args);
}
```

is all it takes. [Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b5993ae4522ad7ac)

Output:

```
Hellobravenewworld!
1234
```

Research [variadic templates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template),
[parameter packs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack)
and [fold expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold)
rather than variadic macros, which are rarely useful in modern C++.

Comment: Okay! Thanks for the advice. The code it quite brilliant :-)

Comment: @BlurryZombie You're welcome. The code is entirely commonplace. You just need to learn about the features I mentioned.

Comment: thanks, but it would be nice to have the \n added automatically

Comment: @jokoon I was able to get the \n added automatically in the c++11/14 version by updating "void log(){}" to "void log(){std::cout << std::endl;}"

Comment: Also, I wish I could have a version, without cout, meaning something that concatenate several strings into one.

Comment: @jokoon iirc you can replace the destination with a stringstream (instead of cout), and concatenate several strings into one, albeit using an intermediate stringstream variable.

Answer (score 14):

When using variadic macros you need `__VA_ARGS__` to expand all the arguments.
The problem however is that those arguments are comma-separated. Presumabely it just separates arguments to a function call, but since macros works with just text you can actually use `__VA_ARGS__` in other contexts as well, where a comma-separated list makes sense.

The trick you can employ is to define your own *comma operator* for `std::ostream` (the type of `std::cout`). For example:

```
#include<iostream>
#define LOG(...) std::cout , __VA_ARGS__ , std::endl

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator,(std::ostream& out, const T& t) {
  out << t;
  return out;
}

//overloaded version to handle all those special std::endl and others...
std::ostream& operator,(std::ostream& out, std::ostream&(*f)(std::ostream&)) {
  out << f;
  return out;
}

int main() {
  LOG("example","output","filler","text");
  return 0;
}
```

Now, the LOG invocation will expand to:

```
std::cout , "example" , "output" , "filler" , "text" , std::endl;
```

and the commas will invoke the overloaded comma operators.

If you don't like overloaded `operator,` polluting all `std::ostream`-s, you can encapsulate `std::cout` with your own special logger class.

Comment: isn't `__VA_ARGS__` gcc-specific?

Comment: To my knowledge `__VA_ARGS__` is supported in every C/C++ compiler that supports variadic macros in the first place. Variadic macros are standard in C and C++11 but not C++.

Comment: thanks, didn't know they make it into C++11. to-the-point answer, upvoted

Comment: C++ is C++14. Do you mean the support was dropped between C++11 and C++14?

Comment: I mean old C++, before C++11. That will be C++03? (not an expert on standards...)

Answer (score 3):

Not sure there is any way of defining a variadic macro in C++ (at least, not a portable way). Why don't you use a variadic template approach? Something like

```
#include <iostream>

void LOG() {}

template<typename Head, typename... Args>
void LOG(const Head& head, const Args&... args )
{
    std::cout << head << " ";
    LOG(args...);
}

int main()
{
    LOG("This", "is" , "the", 3, "rd test");
}
```

Comment: You need a termination condition to stop that template being infinitely recursive.

Comment: @Peter that's what the `void LOG()` does

Answer (score -3):

You can try this one

```
#include <iostream>

#define LOG() std::cout

int main()
{
    LOG() << "Hello! " << "how " << "are " << "you " << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Hello!  how are  you
```