# Convert __VA_ARGS__ to string

Tags: c++, string, variadic-macros

I'm trying to redefine a Variadic Macro to use cout instead of printf. Here's the original code:

```
#define LOGE(...) PRINT_LEVEL(1, __VA_ARGS__);

  #define PRINT_LEVEL(level,...) do { \
      if (debug_components.DEBUG_COMPONENT >= level) \
          { printf("[%s]: ", levels_strings[level-1]); printf(__VA_ARGS__); printf("\n"); } \
    }while(0)
```

I converted this to the following to use cout instead of printf:

```
  #define PRINT_LEVEL(level,...) do { \
if (debug_components.DEBUG_COMPONENT >= level) \
{ std::string argString; sprintf(argString, __VA_ARGS__); std::cout << "[" << levels_strings[level-1] << "]" << argString << "\n";} \
    }while(0)
```

For some reason, `__VA_ARGS__` works fine with printf, but NOT sprintf. It also does not work with cout. I'd like to know the correct way to convert `__VA_ARGS__` to a string, or failing that, the correct way to just print it out using cout.

Comment: Be careful, snprintf take a buffer for first argument.

Comment: Still doesn't work. See the edited code above; now I'm getting the following error:

Comment: candidate function not viable: no known
      conversion from 'std::string' (aka 'basic_string<char>') to
      'char *__restrict' for 1st argument
extern int sprintf (char *__restrict __s,

Comment: Never use macros. Use functions. Want them inlined for sake of efficiency? Let it have internal linkage by making it a `static` non-member function.

Comment: You can't `sprintf` or `snprintf` to a `std::string`. You can't do this properly in a macro.

Comment: @user1765354 Note that there are better ways in C++ 11 and above to have variable arguments, namely using variadic templates and parameter packs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sprintf` takes an extra argument, the data buffer to write the output to. You can't swap out `printf` for `sprintf` without making the changes to provide that buffer. It also doesn't return a pointer to the string, so you can't assign the result to a `std::string` and expect it to work. If you're operating unsafely (assuming a maximum buffer length), something as simple as:

```
#define PRINT_LEVEL(level,...) do { \
    if (debug_components.DEBUG_COMPONENT >= level) \
    { 
        char buf[1024];
        sprintf(buf, __VA_ARGS__); std::cout << "[" << levels_strings[level-1] << "]" << buf << "\n";} \
}while(0)
```

would work (and with truncation, could be done with safety if not reliably via `snprintf`), but if you're using C++ types anyway, you might want to look at [a non-`printf`-y solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29326784/364696)

Comment: Beat me to it! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was using sprintf wrong. Here's the correct code:

```
char argString[1024]; sprintf(argString, __VA_ARGS__);
```

Now argString holds the value of **VA_ARGS**.