# how to write a macro function which has multiple arguments

Tags: c++

I have to write a macro function which takes multiple argument and print them.
e.g,

```
int main(){
    int x,y;
    x=5;
    y=9;
    cout<<"value of x is::"<<x<<" "<<"value of y is:::"<<y<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I want to write a macro which takes x and y as argument and print same as above.
like *debug_print(x,y).*

Comment: So, what's stopping you from writing said macro? Note: why macro instead of a function?

Comment: My general advice is: Don't do that. Avoid macros as much as you can (and then avoid them some more). However, if that's not possible then you have to tell us what you have tried, and how id worked (or not worked). And if you know how to create single-argument macros, then it should not be hard to extrapolate and at least *guess* how a two-argument macro should be.

Comment: what's your problem? You clearly already know the Syntax for multi-argument Macros, what problem did you run into?

Comment: Don't do that. Just [write C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29326784/1362568)

Comment: I wrote the macro function which is #define debug_print(x,y)(cout<<"x is::<<x<<" "<<"y is::<<Y");  and called that function in my code as debug_print(a,b).   but it is not working

Comment: Can you put all that in your question and put the error message in as well please?

Comment: Take care where you put your quotes. And please edit your question to have a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the non-working code. Then while editing your question, please copy-paste the full and complete output of the compiler into the body of the question, if there is any of course. And *tell* us *how* "it is not working".

Answer (score 0):

What you want to look into are [**variadic macros**](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html) if you want a **variadic number of parameters**. Using those, you can define a macro like this

```
#define debug_print(...) <your code here>
```

in the `<your code here>` section you can then use [`__VA_ARGS__`](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson17.html).

---

If you only want to use **two parameters**, you can define the macro like this:

```
#define debug_print(x, y) (std::cout << "value of x is::" << x << " " << "value of y is:::" << y << std::endl)
```

and use it like

```
int x = 5;
int y = 9;
debug_print(x, y);
```

---

As the others have already said, please *do not use this macro* unless you absolutely must! E.g. you don't see that `debug_print` needs `iostream` to work, and you don't see which types can be passed into it.

Comment: *"in the `<your code here>` section you can then use `__VA_ARGS__`"* - A bit of a cop out on your part if I may say so. It's not at all obvious how to complete `<your code here>`, especially to a novice.

Comment: @StoryTeller you are very right on that point; it's just that 1. I haven't really worked with variadic arguments myself, so instead of putting potentially wrong code, I just linked to a tutorial and 2. the `<your code here>` part depends heavily on what the OP wants to do, especially because it seems like they only want 2 parameters, so variadic arguments are overkill anyways. Thank you for your feedback :)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It is working

Comment: @AnamikaKumari glad to hear that it's working for you!