# how should I remove variadic functions?

Tags: c++, variadic-functions

I read that variable argument functions are no good coding.

I have a very old framework with some variable argument functions I want to remove the variable arguments keeping the debugging function.

```
DEBUG(wchar_t* text, ...)
```

This debug function calls a printf-like function using the same string sintaxis %d,%f... etc.

What should be the right approach?

Comment: You could use boost.format perhaps?

Comment: Different question with [same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29326784/1362568)

Comment: I would not change that. Functions with variadic parameter lists are fine for printing, logging etc. Unless you want to change it to C++ and a stream-like interface. Which, of course, would be a major code change.

Comment: You *could* do a whole bunch of re-writing such that all your format strings are changed to be `debug_stream << "Whatever" << args << "here" << etc;`, but it doesn't seem worthwhile. "are no good coding" isn't terribly persuasive against "currently works fine"

Comment: this is exactly what I thought I should be doing

Comment: @caleth the main problem here is that a bug was found in the inner printf-like function when parsing the arguments, so, as is planned to refactor it, I was willing to "C++"-cify it.

Comment: Note that you cannot convert this directly to a `std::cout`-based solution. All the existing formats will be using `%s`, as the question explicitly states. `std::cout` cannot do anything with that. +1 for Matthieu Brucher; Boost.Format **does** understand `%s`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surprisingly I would recommend to leave the debugging function as it is, unless you are willing to change the entire interface to the C++ way of IO, aka streams. If you are going to use `printf` and `printf` syntax then let it as it is. Otherwise modernize it all the way.

For instance let's stay your implementation is somewhere along the lines:

```
void dbg(char* txt, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, txt);
    vprintf(txt, args);
    va_end(arts);
}
```

Yes, there are options to get rid of the variadic, but there is 0 gain in doing so if you are going to keep the `printf` family syntax:

```
template <class... Args>
auto dbg(const char* fmt, const Args&... args)
{
    printf(fmt, args...);
}
```

Then you realize that `char*` is more `C` than `C++` and you change to this:

```
template <class... Args>
auto dbg(const std::string& fmt, const Args&... args)
{
    printf(fmt.c_str(), args...);
}
```

Then you realize that `printf` is more `C` than `C++` and the option now is to get rid of `printf` and to scrap this altogether.

This question [How to make a variadic macro for std::cout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29326460/how-to-make-a-variadic-macro-for-stdcout/29326784#29326784) shows you a way you could do that if you are still set on a function:

```
template<typename ...Args>
void log(Args && ...args)
{
    (std::cout << ... << args);
}
```

Another option is to make something like this:

```
log << "this is the " << i << " log";
```

But it's not trivial to make it add a newline at the end.

In the end, the best solution I think is to use a logging library.

Comment: question, is the va_end unnecesary in the first code?

Comment: Error on my part. Corrected and thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Since you marked the question `c++`, you could make a new class/function based on `c++` streams for instance - perhaps even changing the 'old' system to use your new one. Then *over time* migrate towards that system and perhaps at some point you could get a rid of the old (the 'DEBUG' in your case).

Answer (score 1):

I agree @bolov recommendation to leave the debugging function as it is.
However you may play with `std::initializer_list` and `std::variant` (since C++17) types.
Below is a small example that doesn't yet process the format specifiers but can give some ideas to evolve the approach.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <variant>

typedef std::variant<std::string, int, float, bool> DebugOutParam;
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const DebugOutParam& v)  
{  
    if (std::holds_alternative<std::string>(v))
        os << std::get<std::string>(v);
    else if (std::holds_alternative<int>(v))
        os << std::get<int>(v);
    else if (std::holds_alternative<float>(v))
        os << std::get<float>(v);
    else if (std::holds_alternative<bool>(v))
        os << (std::get<bool>(v) ? "true" : "false");
    else
        os << "?Unsupported?";
    return os;  
}
typedef std::initializer_list<DebugOutParam> DebugOutParams;

void dbg(std::string fmt, DebugOutParams l)
{
    std::cout << fmt << ": ";
    for (DebugOutParams::const_iterator it = l.begin(); it != l.end(); it++)
    {
        DebugOutParam v = *it;
        std::cout << (it == l.begin() ? "" : ", ") << v;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
   dbg("Test", {123, std::string("456"), true, static_cast<float>(456.789)});
}
```

Output

```
Test: 123, 456, true, 456.789
```