# Modern C++ Alternative to __VA_ARGS__?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

In Herb Sutter's cppcon talk, he stated (again) that they have ambitions to get rid of macros entirely and replace it with modern C++ stuff.

I am using the following macro for logging in printf-style (will most likely change to *fmtlib*, though) and I am wondering, how to get rid of macros in that case.

```
#define LOG_INFO(...)       do { printf("INFO:    "); printf(__VA_ARGS__); printf(" | file[%s] line[%d]\n", __FILE__, __LINE__); } while(0)
```

I don't see how this could be done without macros because of `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` alone. But I'm also not aware of any replacement for `__VA_ARGS__`. Does such a thing exist?

Comment: Variadic templates? As to `__FILE__` and `__LINE__`, you are looking for `source_location`.

Comment: You are looking at the wrong part: I'm not aware of any proposal adding a replacement for token-pasting (`##`) and stringizing (`#`), or general token-handling, like needed for example in [tag:x-macros], or for generating many blobs of source.

Comment: you can write function `void LogInfo(PCSTR file, ULONG line, PCSTR format, ...)` and use macro `#define LOG_INFO(...) LogInfo(__FILE__, __LINE__, __VA_ARGS__)`

Comment: @Deduplicator: "*I'm not aware of any proposal adding a replacement for token-pasting (##) and stringizing (#), or general token-handling, like needed for example in x-macros, or for generating many blobs of source.*" Find any proposal about generative reflection and/or metaclasses, coupled with compile-time string manipulation (which C++20 already has). Now, that's not a general replacement for *all* such macro uses, but if it covers 99% of the cases where a library exposes a macro as part of the library's interface, isn't that good enough?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a variadic macro for std::cout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29326460/how-to-make-a-variadic-macro-for-stdcout)