# Variable parameter function

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013

Consider:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdarg.h>

int sum(int, ...);

int main(void)
{
    int answer = sum(4, 4, 3, 2, 1);
    printf("합은 %d입니다.\n", answer);

    return 0;
}

int sum(int num, ...)
{
    int answer = 0;
    va_list argptr;

    va_start(argptr, num);
    for (; num > 0; num--)
        answer += va_arg(argptr, int);

    va_end(argptr);
    return(answer);
}
```

This is a *variable* parameter function.

What is the "`stdarg.h`"? I couldn't find it in my book about `va_list`, `va_end`, and `va_start`.

Comment: It may be useful to see [Variable number of arguments in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1657883/1708801)

Comment: Disagree that "Variable number of arguments in C++?" is a good duplicate 1) It is tagged C++ and not C like this one.  2) A highly rated answer goes off into "Variadic functions"

Comment: @chux agreed, I don't think it is a good dup, I don't think I have seen the C version of that question.

Comment: What book are you using? It could be outdated or simply wrong, or you could be looking at the wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

The header "stdarg.h" is a standard C header which declares some macros useful for dealing with the functions with varying number of arguments of varying types. The most important macros declared are `va_list`, `va_start`, `va_end` and `va_arg`.

The macro `va_list` represents an abstract datatype that can store the "unnamed" arguments of the function call (those that are captured by the "..."). To use it, you must first initialize it, using `va_start()` macro:

```
va_list argptr; /* declaration of the unnamed arguments list */
va_start(argptr, num); /* the initialization of the list */
```

The second parametar of `va_start()` must be the last named parameter of the function (in your case, this is `num`, which is the only named parameter provided). After the initialization, you can extract the unnamed arguments from the `argptr` list one by one, using `va_arg()` macro:

```
answer += va_arg(argptr, int);
```

Each call of `va_arg()` returns the next argument from `argptr`, interpreting it as `int` (or any other type that is provided as the second argument of `va_arg()`). Notice that there is no type-checking and there is no way to be sure that the caller has actually provided the arguments of correct types.

Finally, the list should be released at the end by calling `va_end(argptr)` before returning.