# Why is the unsuitable overloaded function is called?

Tags: c++, overloading

Why does the following code always prints "type is double"? (I have seen this code in StackOverflow)

```
#include <iostream>


void show_type(...) {
    std::cout << "type is not double\n";
}

void show_type(double value) { 
    std::cout << "type is double\n"; 
}

int main() { 
    int x = 10;
    double y = 10.3;

    show_type(x);
    show_type(10);
    show_type(10.3);
    show_type(y);


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution says:

> A standard conversion sequence is always *better* than a user-defined conversion sequence or an ellipsis conversion sequence.

Answer (score 1):

```
   void show_type(double value) { 
        std::cout << "type is double\n"; 
    }
```

if u comment above line then  output will be

> ```
> type is not double
> type is not double
> type is not double
> type is not double
> ```

it means that compile always prefer the `void show_type(double value)` over  `void show_type(...)`.

in your case if you want call the method void show_type(...) pass the two or more arguments when u calling this method `show_type(firstParameter,secondParameter)`

```
#include <iostream>


void show_type(...) {
    std::cout << "type is not double\n";
}

void show_type(double value) { 
    std::cout << "type is double\n"; 
}

int main() { 
    int x = 10;
    double y = 10.3;

    show_type(x);
    show_type(10);
    show_type(10.3);
    show_type(y);
    show_type(4.0,5); //will called this  method show-type(...) 


    return 0;
}
```

now the output of above line will be

> ```
> type is  double
> type is  double
> type is  double
> type is  double
> type is not double  //notice the output here
> ```

[more info on var-args](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657883/variable-number-of-arguments-in-c)