# How can I convert optional parameter method declared in C into c++

Tags: c++, c, optional-parameters

I'm converting some old C-code into c++ and come across something strange, the C-code declared in .h file says:
`void        Message(char *s, ...);`
and implementation head in .c

```
void Message(char *s, long x1, long x2, long x3, long x4, long x5, long x6, long x7, long x8, long x9, long x10){...}
```

When I make a 'straight' copy into a class declaration and implementation  in c++ I  get "prototype error".

Do I need to make a complete declaration as in the .c file oris there another way for c++ and class usage?
The x1 ... x10 is option parameters and rarely used.

Working in linux with g++ and NetBeans 7.3

Comment: You *do* know about default arguments in C++? If not then I suggest you [find a good beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and read about it.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657883/variable-number-of-arguments-in-c

Comment: This C code just love its undefined behavior, doesn't it?

Comment: That only "worked" (term used very loosely) in C because C doesn't encode parameter types as an implementation-dependent mangled name, and you used a left-to-right calling convention with caller-cleanup for parameters passed. C++ is much, *much* more strict about this. You can still use variable-arguments (see Groben's link), but can't do stuff like this and expect it to work (and honestly, you wouldn't want to in the first place).

Comment: The ellipses does not really mean "optional".  The function that implements `...` is supposed to use the `<stdarg.h>` facilities (`va_start`, `va_arg` etc.) to retrieve those trailing parameters.  Even C++ has `...`, so there is a distinction between `...` and optional parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C code shouldn't compile. To implement optional arguments in C++, put their values in the declaration:

```
void Message(char *s, long x1 = 0L, long x2 = 0L, long x3 = 0L, long x4 = 0L, long x5 = 0L,
        long x6 = 0L, long x7 = 0L, long x8 = 0L, long x9 = 0L, long x10 = 0L);
```

And then define your function like this:

```
void Message(char *s, long x1, long x2, long x3, long x4, long x5,
        long x6, long x7, long x8, long x9, long x10)
{
    // Function body
}
```

Note that you only need to specify the default values in one place. Do it in the declaration so that they're visible to clients.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I implemented your suggestion and that solved it for me.