# What is the meaning of "..." in printf(const char *_Format, ...)

Tags: c++

I think this question already exists. But I can't search for the keyword "...". How to declare and use function with "...". Hope someone can help me solve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: [varargs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic)

Comment: AFAIK, it means there is no limit of params. When you set a format for the char array, you may need several parameters, since it is not a fixed value, you are free to define as many as you want.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657883/variable-number-of-arguments-in-c

Comment: Very grateful if you give me an example.

Comment: If you are learning C++ you probably don't want to do this. It is possible to overload functions with the same name and different (but fixed) number of parameters. In C you cannot do that, and will have to use this sledge hammer.

Comment: thank you very much