# Undefined symbols Variadic function

Tags: c++, variadic-functions

I am trying to create a method that allows for a variable number of inputs. I was trying to implement [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16338804/7112888) answer (see the code below) however, I got an error when I tried to run my code.

#### Code

header:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
void vSend ( T tIn, Args... AArgs );
template <typename T>
void vSend ( T tIn );
```

CPP

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
void Connector::vSend ( T tIn, Args... AArgs )
{
    pPacketToSend << tIn;

    vSend(AArgs...);
}

template <typename T>
void Connector::vSend ( T tIn )
{
    pPacketToSend << tIn;

    tSocket.send(pPacketToSend);
}
```

#### Error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "void Connector::vSend<int, int>(int, int)", referenced from:
      Updater::Update(sf::Image*) in updatedirector.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

## Edit (Answer)

Turns out templates may only be implemented in the header file.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh is probably right. pudility, can you throw us a bone and tell us what is in a header and what isn't?

Comment: @user4581301 sorry about that, I have updated my question.

Comment: It's an exact duplicate then. You must put all templates in header files.