# Modern C++ best way to implement a function with a variable number of int parameters

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17, variadic-templates

In modern C++(ie, version>=11), what is best way to implement a function with a variables number of int parameters?

**I only want `int`s, not a general type.**

Each of the parameters is of type int and no other type is allowed.

```
void foo(/*WHAT'S HERE*/) {
// and how do I access the arguments here?
}

int main()
{
  foo(34,1);
  foo(9,2,66,1);
  // etc
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I added another question to the duplicate list that covers restricting arguments to int

Comment: Why not pass in a `vector<int>`?

Comment: Why wouldn't this work: https://ideone.com/TvLalR

Comment: @M.M  Many, many, ..., many thank yous. The following works in C++17 and is a thing of immense beauty.
```template <typename... U>
typename std::enable_if<(std::is_same<U, int>::value && ...), void>::
type foo(U... ints) {
  const int size = sizeof...(ints);
  int intarray[size] = {ints...};
}```

Comment: @RFS beauty is in the eye of the beholder :)

Answer (score -1):

The best thing to do is use a variadic function.

```
template<typename T, typename ... Args>
return_type Functionname(T arg1, ...)
{ }
```

For example, if you want to sum a variable number of arguments, use something like:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
T adder(T first, Args... args) {
  return first + adder(args...);
}
```

Hope this helps!

EDIT:  This question might help, too.

[Variable number of arguments in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657883/variable-number-of-arguments-in-c?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: How do I do this for int's? I only want int's.

Comment: Your syntax for the function parameters in the first snippet is not doing what you expect it to. You are declaring a variadic template for a (C-style) variadic function. The `adder` example lacks a base case and since C++17 fold expressions are a much more readable way of forming that example. Replacing `typename` by `int` makes the parameters non-type template parameters and your last code block ill-formed, because `Args` are not types.

Comment: @RFS The variadic template accepts *any* types for *any* argument, so it works fine with `int` arguments. If your question is how to limit the variadic template to *only* accept `int` as argument, then you should clarify that in the question.

Comment: @GokuMizuno "Replace all typename with int" is not possible