# How can I pass std::initializer_list in a variable number of arguments?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-functions, initializer-list

I would like to pass a `std::initializer_list` inside a variable number of arguments for a function that print each argument.

```cpp
func( 1, 2.5, 'a', "Hello", {10, 20, 30, 40 } );
```

Expecting this output:

```
1
2.5
a
Hello
{ 10, 20, 30, 40, }
```

I tried to implement it following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16338804/22311077) from another question.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

template <typename T>
void func_(std::initializer_list<T> list ) 
{
    std::cout << "{ ";
    for( const T& elem : list )
    {
       std::cout << elem << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << "}" << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
void func_(T t) 
{
    std::cout << t << std::endl;
}

void func(){}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
void func(T t, Args... args) // recursive variadic function
{
    func_(t);
    func(args...) ;
}

int main()
{
    func( 1,2.5,'a', "Hello", {10, 20, 30, 40 });
}
```

Another way that I tried to implemented `func`

```cpp
template <typename T, typename S>
void func(T t) 
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same<T, std::initializer_list<S>>::value)
    {
        std::cout << "{ ";
        for( const S& elem : t )
        {
            std::cout << elem << ", ";
        }
        std::cout << "}" << std::endl;
    }
    else
        std::cout << t << std::endl;
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
void func(T t, Args... args) // recursive variadic function
{
    func(t);
    func(args...);
}
```

None of them worked

Comment: Unfortunately, C++ simply doesn't work this way, on a fundamental level. Braced initialization lists are typeless and cannot be forwarded via a universal reference.

Comment: Your problem is that `{10, 20, 30, 40 }` doesn't have a type, so it'll never get deduced in a template.  You need to make `{10, 20, 30, 40 }` some sort of concrete type explicitly.

Comment: Since `{...}` does not have a type, you can create a class with overloaded `operator<<` and then specify that class name explicitly as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77930701/12002570).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **problem** is that a *braced init list does not have a type*. So we have to explicitly specify the type specifier.

The simplest way I can think of is to create a class with an `std::initializer_list` ctor and overloaded `operator<<` and then use it as shown below.

```
template<typename T>
struct V
{
    V(std::initializer_list<T> v): m_t(v){}
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const V& v)
    {
        std::cout << "{ ";
        for(const auto i: v.m_t)  
        {
             std::cout << i << " "; 
        }
        std::cout << "}";
        return os;
    }
    std::initializer_list<T> m_t;
};
func_( 1,2.5,'a', "Hello", V{10, 20, 30, 40 }); //works now
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/j4xMx7nWx)

The output of the above program is(the same as your expected output):

```
1
2.5
a
Hello
{ 10 20 30 40 }
```

It can be further customized as per your needs.