# Weird characters in printf

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, printf, objective-c++

My environment: Xcode5, iOS, Objective-C/Objective-C++ mix.

I am trying to figure out what causes the next problem. I am writing my own logging function:

```
int _me_log(const char *fmt, ...) {

va_list args;
va_start(args, fmt);

char *c = va_arg(args, char *);

char *message = NULL;

printf(fmt, args);

int n = asprintf(&message, fmt, args);

if (n != -1 && message != NULL) {
 //do something with 'message' like writing to file, etc.
 UPDATE:
//we need to handle memory created for 'message' storage.
free(message); 
}
va_end(args);

return n;

}
```

Then I call it like this:

```
_me_log("socket %s did open", "Socket: 0x1fd1c880");
```

And instead of correct output `socket Socket: 0x1fd1c880  did open` I get some gibberish like this `socket \\323\331/ did open` in this line `printf(fmt, args);`.

If I call it this way `printf("%s", c);` I get correct results.

I have googled several implementations ([this](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~jws9c/temple/307Fall2002/stdarg/) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056411/how-to-pass-variable-number-of-arguments-to-printf-sprintf) ) of logging functions and functions which pass variable parameters and it seems that I do everything correctly.

Could you please suggest me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like you want `vasprintf` instead of `asprintf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got the right idea to use `va_list` here, but if you work with `va_list` you should use `vasprintf` instead of `asprintf`:

```
int _me_log(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    char *message = NULL;
    int n;

    va_start(args, fmt);
    n = vasprintf(&message, fmt, args);

    if (n != -1 && message != NULL) {
        // ... use message ...
    }
    free(message);
    va_end(args);

    return n;
}
```

For every routine of the `printf` family, there is a variant that takes a `va_list` instead of the variadic argument `...` and whose name is prefixed with the letter `v`, for example:

```
int printf(const char *format, ...);
int vprintf(const char *format, va_list ap);
```

These routines exist so you can write you own (non-macro) wrapper for `xprintf`.

Comment: Thanks, I have already added a comment to previous answer. I am accepting you answer because it provides direct answer to my question and code in it. trojanfoe's answer is also correct.

Comment: @trojanfoe if you mean leaking 'message' then of course I handle that. I omitted it for code brevity.

Comment: Updated question with freeing of 'message' memory. Just in case someone copy/pastes it.

Comment: OK that makes more sense, however the call to `free()` which is now in this answer is in the wrong place.

Comment: @trojanfoe: Of course the message buffer must be freed. User1264176 beat me to editing the answer. Thanks for correcting that.

Comment: @trojanfoe: It's only in the wrong place if `vasprintf` guarantees that the buffer is `NULL` if and only if -1 is returned. It is legal (if unnecessary) or `free(NULL)`.

Comment: And what will `free(NULL)` do?

Comment: @trojanfoe: It won't do anything. It's probably so you don't have to check for `NULL` in client code. But I agree with you in principle: Had the condition just been `if (message) ...` it would have been cleaner to free the buffer at the end of the `if` block.

Comment: Ah OK - on some systems that will blow up - not under OSX/iOS I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a very complicated implementation.  Try:

```
int _me_log(const char *fmt, ...) {
    int ret = 0;
    va_list va;
    va_start(va, fmt);
    ret = vprintf(fmt, va);
    va_end(va);

    putc('\n', stdout);
    return ret;
}
```

But, of course, that is no different from `printf()`, except for forcing a newline.

Comment: Now I see my mistake. You can't call printf with va_list as a parameter like this "printf(fmt, va);". You have to call vprintf() instead. Thanks.