# How do I sprintf an array given a unknown format string?

Tags: c

As the title states, how do I sprintf an array given a unknown format string? I.e. how do I fill in `my_sprintf`?

```
char* my_sprintf(const char *format, char **args){
    char *result = malloc(MAX_SIZE_STRING*sizeof(char));
    // ???
    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    printf("%s\n", my_sprintf("%s %s %s", argv));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you asking about how to make your own sprintf from scratch or just to pass a variable list of arguments to the appropriate functions?  This existing thread covers the wrapping: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056411/how-to-pass-variable-number-of-arguments-to-printf-sprintf

Comment: This is actually not possible without parsing `format` yourself, which is a similar amount of work to just fully implementing `sprintf` yourself, or doctoring a freeware implementation of `sprintf`.  However, if the calling function can pass `va_list args` instead of `char **args`, then you can use `vsprintf` (or preferably, `vsnprintf`).

Comment: It's not clear if you want to be able to handle `%d`, `%f`, `%-20.15s`, etc. (and if so, how you are going to pass the args in). If your function only expects to handle `%s` exactly and nothing else, then this is possible.

Comment: @MattMcNabb no, I understand that the others arent possible. I only intended `%s` with the modifiers and such.

Comment: @JamesSnyder its not about a "variable list of arguments" its about an array, specifically (unless if there is a way to convert an array to a va_list)

Comment: Are you asking for someone to do your homework? If not, show what you've attempted.

Comment: @ooga no..this is not homework. as to the reason there is no "attempt" is that I was hoping that there would be a simple function call that does this.

Comment: @chacham15 any reason you need it in a single string?  You could just iterate through your argc printing each one.  Otherwise you could concatenate them like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308695/c-string-concatenation The former won't require such a large buffer, but in the latter case you can count the lengths and make a buffer of the exact needed length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This answer takes into account OP's comment "I only intended %s with the modifiers and such")

Note that it is *possible* to build your own `va_list`, however the details of this are implementation-specific and extremely non-portable, so I'm not going to go down that road.

This is arguably the simplest way to do it:

```
if ( argc == 1 ) snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, format, argv[0]);
else if ( argc == 2 ) snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, format, argv[0], argv[1]);
else if ( argc == 3 ) snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, format, argv[0], argv[1], argv[2]);
// ...etc, so far as you want
```

You work out `argc` by looping through `argv` until you find `NULL`  (`argv[argc]` is guaranteed to be `NULL`).

This code uses a fixed buffer size `char buf[MAX_LENGTH];`, and then you can `strdup` to create your return value or whatever. If you want to avoid the `MAX_LENGTH` limitation then you have to call `snprintf` twice for each case: once to find out the length required; then `malloc`, then call it again to do the actual printing.

If you would prefer a less cut-and-paste'y version there is an outline of the algorithm you will need:

1. Find `argc`
2. Tokenize `format`. (If you are writing the code that generates format, you could just supply a list of tokens instead of a string)
3. For each token, Call `snprintf(buf + upto, space_remaining, token, argv[i++]);`

While doing this, you'll need to keep track of how much of `buf` you have used up (and `realloc` it at each step, if you are going to use the double-`snprintf` method). Also check you stop before reaching `argc`.

Answer (score 1):

Too much time on my hands tonight, so here's a simple - if not all that particularly efficient - way. I'm taking you at your word literally when you say "I only intended `%s` with the modifiers and such", in particular this won't cope with `%%` and such:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

const static size_t initial_list_size = 20;


/*
 * Returns a list of indices of `format` at which the substring
 * "%s" is located. -1 is the sentinel value for end of list.
 * Caller is responsible for freeing the returned pointer.
 */

int * find_specifiers(const char * format) {
    size_t list_size = initial_list_size, top = 0;

    /*  Dynamically allocate list for locations of specifiers  */

    int * loc_list = malloc(list_size * sizeof *loc_list);
    if ( loc_list == NULL ) {
        fputs("Error allocating memory.", stderr);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    loc_list[top] = -1;

    /*  Find all occurrences  */

    const char * needle = format;
    while ( (needle = strstr(needle, "%s")) != NULL ) {

        /*  Add index of found substring to list  */

        loc_list[top++] = needle - format;

        /*  Increase size of list if necessary  */

        if ( top >= list_size ) {
            list_size *= 2;
            loc_list = realloc(loc_list, list_size * sizeof *loc_list);
            if ( loc_list == NULL ) {
                fputs("Error allocating memory.", stderr);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }

        /*  Set new sentinel value and skip past current specifier  */

        loc_list[top] = -1;
        needle += 2;
    }

    return loc_list;
}


/*
 * Returns a dynamically allocated string equivalent to `format`
 * with each occurrence in `format` of "%s" replaced with successive
 * strings in the array pointed to by `args`. Caller is responsible
 * for freeing the returned pointer.
 */

char * my_sprintf(const char *format, char **args){
    int * loc_list = find_specifiers(format);
    size_t outsize = strlen(format) + 1;

    /*  Calculate required size of output string  */

    for ( size_t i = 0; loc_list[i] != -1; ++i ) {
        outsize += strlen(args[i]) - 2;
    }

    /*  Allocate output string with calloc() to avoid
     *  the need to manually null-terminate.           */

    char *result = calloc(1, outsize);
    if ( result == NULL ) {
        fputs("Error allocating memory.", stderr);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /*  Copy `format`, and replace specifiers with
     *  successive strings contained in `args`      */

    size_t n_out = 0, current_spec = 0, n_fmt = 0;
    while ( format[n_fmt] ) {

        /*  Copy the next argument  */

        if ( loc_list[current_spec] != -1 &&
            n_fmt == (size_t) loc_list[current_spec] ) {
            size_t n_arg = 0;
            while ( args[current_spec][n_arg] ) {
                result[n_out++] = args[current_spec][n_arg++];
            }
            ++current_spec;
            n_fmt += 2;
        }
        else {

            /*  Copy the next character of `format`  */

            result[n_out++] = format[n_fmt++];
        }
    }

    free(loc_list);
    return result;
}

int main(void){
    char * args[] = {"These", "are", "args"};
    char * result1 = my_sprintf("Arg 1: %s, Arg 2: %s, Arg 3 %s", args);
    char * result2 = my_sprintf("There are no args here.", NULL);

    printf("%s\n", result1);
    printf("%s\n", result2);

    free(result1);
    free(result2);

    return 0;
}
```

which outputs:

```
paul@MacBook:~/Documents/src/scratch$ ./mysprint
Arg 1: These, Arg 2: are, Arg 3 args
There are no args here.
paul@MacBook:~/Documents/src/scratch$
```