# passing variable parameter list to syslog

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, syslog

I try to pass a variable parameter list to another function. There is already a very similary question: [How to pass variable number of arguments to printf/sprintf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056411/how-to-pass-variable-number-of-arguments-to-printf-sprintf)
But for me it doesn't work. And I don't know why. This is my function:

```
void printSyslogNotice(const char *fmt, ...)
{
      va_list ap;
      va_start(ap, fmt);
      #ifdef __XENO__
         rt_syslog(LOG_NOTICE, fmt, ap);
      #else
         syslog(LOG_NOTICE, fmt, ap);
      #endif
      va_end(ap);
}
```

When I call it with:

```
printSyslogNotice("%s %i", "hello world", 5);
```

I get this output: #010 -939524064

Needless to say, I would like this output: hello world 5

Does somebody has an idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `vsyslog`, not `syslog`. `syslog` receives variable parameters pack, but not `va_list`. If you want to call `syslog` you should pass arguments as is, not by `va_list`.

Comment: +1 beats managing buffers via vsnprintf + malloc any day of the week an twice on sundays.