# Relaying private arguments to derived-class virtual method

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions

Consider the following two classes:

```
class Parent
{
private:
    char outputBuffer[100];

protected:
    virtual void WriteOutput() = 0;
};


class Child : public Parent
{
private:
    double value1;
    double value2;
    void WriteOutput()
    {
        sprintf(outputBuffer, "%.2f %.2f", value1, value2);
    }
};
```

The parent defines a `virtual` function that is then implemented in the child, the purpose of which is to write a formatted string to an output buffer.

My challenge is that I would prefer that the output buffer not be directly visible to the child class. In other words, I want WriteOutput to look like:

```
void WriteOutput()
{
    myFcn("%.2f %.2f", value1, value2);
}
```

But then what does `myFcn()` look like? It should just relay to sprintf but the syntax needed to support the varags in sprintf is confusing me. Is it possible to relay a variable number of arguments? I'm showing two values in the example but different children will have different number of values so I have to preserve the vararg capability of sprintf. Note that performance is important here so I can't have unnecessary string copies.

If there's a better / more efficient alternative to sprintf in this context I can consider it. Thanks.

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056411/how-to-pass-variable-number-of-arguments-to-printf-sprintf?rq=1) what you're looking for?

Comment: @chris That answer is from 2009. C++11 has much better possibilities.

Comment: Instead of using `vsprintf` at bottom, use a C++ variadic template function. This was one of the most commonly offered examples when variadic templates were introduced.

Comment: Since the function is `virtual`, a `template` won't be applicable (directly).

Comment: @KonradRudolph, Agreed. That was purely for how to pass along the varargs.

Comment: @5gon12eder Fair point. However, rather than mucking around with va_args I’d still use a template and then have a nonvirtual function template wrapper that captures the arguments inside a vector of `std::string`s (or alternatively `std::any` to preserve the original types) and passes them on to the virtual function. Of course that no longer works with `snprintf`.

Answer (score 3):

In [Sutter and Alexandrescu's C++ Coding Standards](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/c++cs.htm), you can find the following item:

> 39. Consider making virtual functions nonpublic, and public functions nonvirtual. 68

I believe that, even though your question did not specifically pertain to the public/private aspects, the rationale there carries here. A non-`virtual` method should say "externally" *what* it does, and a `virtual` method should say *how* it does it.

As such, they need not have the same signature. In fact, how about this:

```
class Parent
{
private:
    char outputBuffer[100];

protected:
    virtual void WriteOutputImp(char outputBuffer[100]) = 0;

public:
    void WriteOutput()
    {
        WriteOutputImp(outputBuffer);
   }
};


class Child : public Parent
{
private:
    double value1;
    double value2;

protected:
    virtual void WriteOutputImp(char outputBuffer[100])
    {
        sprintf(outputBuffer, "%.2f %.2f", value1, value2);
    }
};
```

**Edit** As @5gon12eder correctly (IMHO) mentions, while you're at it, you might consider changing the `char ...[100]` to something safer. That is entirely correct, but a separate point.

Comment: I think this is a very good answer but the `void WriteOutputImp(char outputBuffer[100])` signature is misleading. I'd rather have the function accept a pointer and a length and internally use `snprintf`.

Comment: @5gon12eder Thanks, that sounds very logical. Since that is an orthogonal point, though, then in order to avoid confusion, I think I'll mention it as an after-point. Appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new variadic templates. i.e.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

void write()
{  }

template<typename... Params>
void write(double toPrint, Params... args)
{
    std::string str = "%.2f";
    const int size = sizeof...(args);
    if(size > 0U)
        str += " ";
    sprintf(outputBuffer, str.c_str(), toPrint);

    write(args...);
}
```

You may call this from the individual `WriteOutput` method like `write(5.1, 1.23, mydoublevalue, 9.993)`.
However, you may want to minimize `sprintf` calls, making another method necessary:

```
template<typename... Params>
std::string construct()
{ return std::string(); }

template<typename... Params>
std::string construct(double toPrint, Params... args)
{
    std::string str = "%.2f";
    const int size = sizeof...(args);
    if(size > 0U)
        str += " ";
    str += construct(args...);

    return str;
}

template<typename... Params>
void write(Params... args)
{
    sprintf(outputBuffer, (construct(args...)).c_str(), args...);
}
```

Call is the same, but you use just one `sprintf` call. See it working [online](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9cc4f017151df223)!