# Use one pointer for sprintf variadic argument

Tags: c++, printf

I am writing a function, that takes a variadic argument list and produces a formated string from those. The problem is, that i use sprintf to create the string and i need to explicity list all paramaters, while programming

```
sprintf(string, format, a0, a1, a2, ...);
```

On [cppreference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/) however the description of sprintf says, that ...

> ... (additional arguments)
>       Depending on the format string, the function may expect a sequence of additional arguments, each containing a value to be used to replace
>   a format specifier in the format string (**or a pointer to a storage**
>   **location, for n**).

What i understand like, that i can store all the data to a pointer location and hand the pointer to sprintf.

```
int arr[X];
arr[0] = a0;
...
sprintf(string, format, &arr);
```

Trying that resulted in an unexpected behavior. Only numbers were written to the string.

Does it actually work that way and is there maybe a better solution?

My first attempt was to add each variadic argument separatly to the string, but that produced a lot of calls to sprintf, what i want to avoid.

Is it possible to pass the variadic argument list from one function to another?

Comment: Not specifically a solution, but have you checked out parameter packs?

Comment: working on a micro controller here without C++11 but thanks for your idea, i actually did not check out parameter packs

Comment: Right on.  Another semi-side-note, I do a fair bit of microcontroller dev and C++ 11 *is* generally available.  Are you sure it isn't for you?

Comment: What cppreference is saying is that each of the arguments after the format string is either a value printf will read or a pointer printf will write. Each %n gets its own matching writeable  pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Okay ... why did i not find this sooner...
The solution for me was to use `vsnprintf` instead of `sprintf`. That way one can pass the va_list to a formated string function and it is secure.

[How to pass variable number of arguments to printf/sprintf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056411/how-to-pass-variable-number-of-arguments-to-printf-sprintf)