# Pass va_list down to sprintf results in wrong integer values

Tags: c, printf

I'm trying to encapsulate `sprintf` call in C function with variable number of arguments. The reason is that I want to have a log wrapper to send log via network in JSON format, instead of writing to console. And I don't want to call `sprintf` before every log call, but rather pass format and arguments as in `sprintf` function itself.

I followed this question [How to pass variable number of arguments to printf/sprintf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056411/how-to-pass-variable-number-of-arguments-to-printf-sprintf) and I got string in `format` parameter working correctly, but number arguments printed with `%i` somehow printed wrong.

For example:

instead of `40` I get `1073546032` printed

instead of `0` I get `1073545776` printed

If I do `sprintf` before calling my log function, I see correct numbers in the result string.

Here's my code, but it's exactly same as in other similar question:

```
void write_log(const char* format, ...)
{
    char formatted_string[256];

    va_list argptr;
    va_start(argptr, format);
    int len = sprintf(formatted_string, format, argptr);
    va_end(argptr);

    // formatted_string sent to JSON builder
}
```

Comment: `sprintf()` takes the actual argument not a `va_list`.  Have you tried using `vsprintf()` instead?

Comment: "I followed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056411/how-to-pass-variable-number-of-arguments-to-printf-sprintf) ...": you didn't really, because those answers all use `vsprintf`.

Comment: @NateEldredge yes, you are right, it seems I completely ignored `v` prefix

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [`vsprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/vfprintf).  (But you should really use `vsnprintf` instead so that you don't risk overflowing your buffer.)

All the `*printf` functions come in a `v` version that takes a `va_list` instead of variadic arguments.