# Inputs and outputs of the function void *function(){}

Tags: c, function, pointers

A void function does not return any value as output and can take input values. The function below seems a void function, but there is the operator *, why?

```
void *function(){
     printf("hello")
}
```

Comment: You'll need to study _pointers_ in your beginner-level C programming book. The `*` here is not an operator but part of the return type declaration.

Comment: @Lundin in the C course i studied only void function and void pointer like void *p, but i have never seen void *function.

Comment: It is a function returning a `void *`, simple as that.

Comment: Take a look at this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8911230/what-is-the-function-of-an-asterisk-before-a-function-name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not a `void` function. That is a function that returns a `void*` (pointer). But it seems incomplete, because the `printf()` has no semicolon `;` and the function does not actually return a `void*`.

Comment: can you write an example to understand how to use it please?

Comment: You have to study the pointers chapters. If you have a C book, it has to have a chapter about it. If not, just google it, this topic is far too complex to explain in a SO answer.