# C funcName(void * self)

Tags: c, terminology, self, void

I have never programmed in C, so please can anyone tell me what does this construction do:

```
void funcName(void * self)
{ ... }
```

as far as I understood 
the funcName receives the pointer to the unknown data and this function receives nothing

but why there is a void * self

Comment: You may want to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/692564/concept-of-void-pointer-in-c-programming

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a function that takes a void pointer - a pointer without a specific type. Void pointer type lets you pass a pointer to any data type to a function that is declared like that. The function will have to cast the pointer to an appropriate type before reading/writing the data from it, or pass the pointer on to other functions that take `void*`.

Any pointer can be cast to `void*`, implicitly or explicitly. For example, you can call `funcName` like this:

```
int *ptr = malloc(100*sizeof(int));
funcName(ptr); // No error
```

You can then call the same function with a different pointer type:

```
struct mystruct_t *ptr = malloc(100*sizeof(mystruct_t));
funcName(ptr); // Again, no error
```

Judging from the name of the pointer, `self`, it is likely that the function is trying to emulate object-oriented style of programming with constructs available in C. Instead of passing the pointer to data implicitly the way member-functions do, this style passes a pointer to data explicitly. The pointer is often called `this` or `self`.