# What does method(void * param) mean in C?

Tags: c

I need to know what it means when a function has a `void *` parameter. For example:

```
function(void * param){}
```

Comment: It means that it takes a `void*` as parameter, what else is to know about it?

Comment: I do not understand the upvotes on this question. I am about to downvote it. This information can be found easily on the web.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Concept of void pointer in C programming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/692564/concept-of-void-pointer-in-c-programming)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`param` is a void pointer means pointer to any data type . You may call generic type pointer.

e.g.

```
func(void *param)
{
// body 
}
```

call like this :

```
char* cptr;
int* iptr;
float* fptr;

func(cptr);
func(iptr);
func(fptr);
```

Answer (score 6):

It is a function that receives a `void*`. This may be used to pass any kind of pointer in C.

A good example is the [`pthread_create`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) function, and the pthread start routine.

Note, however, that if no return type is specified, it defaults to return an `int`, which it does not in your example.

Comment: *any kind*, to be accurate well only object pointers not function pointers;)

Comment: @ouah: That depends, and you know it. ;-) In the above example, `pthread_create` is clearly a POSIX function and it's allowed by the POSIX standard.

Comment: @netcoder but there was not `pthread_create` when I wrote my comment, the edit has been done after. And the sentence *This may be used to pass any kind of pointer in C* is still inaccurate.

Answer (score 2):

A `void *` is a pointer to *any* data, i.e. to data of an unknown or unspecified type.

Answer (score 1):

`param` has type `void *`, which in C serves as a "generic" pointer type; any object pointer type can be converted to `void *` and vice versa without need for an explicit cast (some implementations allow function pointer types to be converted to `void *`, but that's not universal and not guaranteed by the language standard).

Note that a `void` pointer may not be dereferenced, so you can't do something like `x = *param` in the body of the function.  You'd have to convert the pointer to a different type such as `int *` or `double *` or whatever to get what it points to.  And that depends on what `function` is supposed to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

It means the param of type void* (reference to a void), which is the size of a memory location . You can reference any memory location with this, which in practice anything.