# Cast void pointer to uint64_t array in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory, void-pointers, dereference

I'm currently working with a Linux kernel module and I need to access some 64-bit values stored in an array, however I first need to cast from a void pointer.

I'm using the kernel function `phys_to_virt` which is returning a void pointer, and I'm not entirely sure how to actually use this void pointer to access elements within the array that it points to.

Currently I'm doing this:

```
void *ptr;
uint64_t test;

ptr = phys_to_virt(physAddr);
test = *(uint64_t*)ptr;
printk("Test: %llx\n", test);
```

The value I'm getting from test isn't what I expected to see within the array, so I'm fairly sure I'm doing something wrong.  I need to access the first three elements in the array, so I need to cast the void pointer to a uint64_t[] but I'm not quite sure how to do that.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The code itself seems valid but mapping physical memory to virtual isn't a valid operation in all cases. What exactly does your `physAddr` point to?

Comment: It should point to a 512 element array containing 64-bit long values.

Comment: But what is this array? Is it in shared memory within external device?

Comment: The cast is fine, the problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: So that cast should be giving me the first element in the array?

Comment: Yup. And `*((uint64_t*)ptr+n)` for the nth member.

Comment: You could also do `uint64_t * ptest = (uint64_t*)ptr; printk("Test: %llx\n", ptest[0]);` to get the array's first element. The code for the second element then is obvious, isn't it? ;-)

Comment: I think I can work that bit out, yes :)  Thanks alk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm using the kernel function phys_to_virt which is returning a void pointer, and I'm not entirely sure how to actually use this void pointer to access elements within the array that it points to.

Yup, [`phys_to_virt()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/include/asm/memory.h?a=avr32#L223) does indeed return a `void *`. The concept of the [`void *`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692564/concept-of-void-pointer-in-c-programming) is that it's typeless, so you can store anything to it, and yes you need to typecast it to something to extract information from it.

```
ptr = phys_to_virt(physAddr); // void * returned and saved to a void *, that's fine

test = *(uint64_t*)ptr; // so: (uint64_t*)ptr is a typecast saying "ptr is now a 
                        //      uint64_t pointer", no issues there
                        // adding the "*" to the front deferences the pointer, and 
                        // deferencing a pointer (decayed from an array) gives you the
                        // first element of it.
```

So yes, `test = *(uint64_t*)ptr;` will correctly typecast and give you the first element of the array. Note you can also write it like this:

```
test = ((uint64_t *)ptr)[0];
```

Which you might find a little bit clearer and means the same thing.