# Using a void pointer as a function paramenter in C

Tags: c, function, pointers, void

I'm trying to create a type generic function in C. As an argument I was passing on a void pointer. (The programmer using the function would be able to pass on a pointer of any type). However, this of course presents problems when dereferencing said pointer in the function. Any ideas as to how I can solve this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Paste the sample code.

Comment: cast it and it should work ;)

Comment: Add a `(char*)p` cast if you have declared a `void* p` parameter.

Comment: This --> [SO post][1] explains everything nicely


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/692564/concept-of-void-pointer-in-c-programming

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804371/syntax-and-sample-usage-of-generics-in-c11

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: would that make the function generic though? (ex: would it work with floats and doubles?)

Comment: @user3126802 a void pointer does not know what it points to. you have to encode the type in the information, e.g. by using a struct, or use non-generic functions. those are probably easier to maintain anyway.

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin I am actually using a struct which contains a void pointer. But I still cannot dereference the pointer no?

Comment: @user3126802 no. but if the struct contains information about the type of the information, then you can cast the void pointer to a pointer of the right type