# Threads creation in C

Tags: c, pthreads

```
void print_hello_world() {
    pid_t pid = getpid();
    printf("Hello world %d\n", pid);
    pthread_exit(0);
}

void main() {
    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, (void *) &print_hello_world, NULL);
    print_hello_world();
}
```

I really couldn't understand what is the need of (void *) in pthread_create. And do we need "&print_hello_world" in the same or could drop "&" as I have read somewhere that while passing function pointers we don't need to place "&" before the function name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there's no need for cast or `&` operator there:

```
pthread_create(&thread, NULL, print_hello_world, NULL);
```

should suffice as a function name gets converted into a function pointer when passing as argument to function(s).

Note that the function pointer you pass to `pthread_create()` takes a `void*` as argument and returns a `void *`. So your function should be:

```
void* print_hello_world(void *unused) {
...
}
```

---

It's the C way of implementing "generic" data type. For example, you can pass a `int*` or `struct args*` to the thread function and retrieve it back. 
E.g.

```
 int i=5;
 pthread_create(&thread, NULL, print_hello_world, &i);
```

and in the function `print_hello_world()`, you would do:

```
void *print_hello_world(void *value) {
  int i = *(int*)value;
  ... 
}
```

Basically `void*` allows you to pass *any* data pointer to the thread function here. If `pthread_create()`'s thread function were to take `int*`, you wouldn't be able to pass a `struct args*` to it, for example.

I suggest you read the following posts for more information on void pointer and its usage in C:

[Concept of void pointer in C programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692564/concept-of-void-pointer-in-c-programming)
and
[What does void* mean and how to use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11626786/what-does-void-mean-and-how-to-use-it?lq=1)

Comment: What could void* possibly mean? As int* mean the return value is an integer pointer. void pointer makes no sense. :/

Comment: Could you pls elaborate? I couldn't understand

Comment: @UtkarshGupta The comment was getting too big. Please see the updated the answer.

Comment: Couldn't we have casted the passed argument from (int*) to (struct*) or vice-versa, had that been the case?

Comment: @UtkarshGupta Casting  `TYPE1 *` to `TYPE2 *` is not guaranteed to work for all types (except casting to a character type: `char *`, `unsigned char*` or `signed char*`). Using `void *` is the only portable way without worrying about aliasing.

Comment: Are you sure about that?

Comment: @Olaf I never said conversion between different pointer types is valid. OP asked "caste[d] the passed argument from from (int*) to (struct*) or vice-versa" and I replied to that. I don't get what you are trying to say.

Comment: @Olaf It's not about the the function pointer but the argument that the thread function takes and value it returns. I added one example with the argument it takes. The same is applicable to the return value too -- both are data pointers. There was no reference to function pointers in my comment.

Comment: Fair point! Sorry, I apparently missed the initial comment of Utkarsh.

Answer (score 2):

Casting a function pointer to/from `void *` is actually *undefined behaviour*. See [6.3.2.3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3), especially p1 and p8. Note that functions are no [*objects*](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.15) in C.

So the cast is wrong in fact and the addressof-operator `&` is unnecessary. You can cast, however, one function pointer to another (see §8 of the reference). But here, you shoud definitively have a proper signature for your function, as there is a reason it takes a pointer and returns one, too. So: **do not cast, but get the signature (and semantics) correct**.

Note: An empty *identifier-list* in a function *declaration* which is part of the *definition* is an [obsolescent feature](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.11.6). Using the prototype-style `(void)` for an empty argument list is recommended. Also the **minimal required** signature for [`main`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1p1) is `int main(void)` (with respect to the above said).

Comment: Could you give a citation for the claim that a function with no arguments must be declared `[type] foo(void)`? Also, the real problem is that `pthread_create()` expects a pointer to a function with of type `void *(*)(void *)`.

Comment: @EOF: For `()` vs. `(void)` I was a bit overhasty; that is just to become obsolete in a future version (hopefully); i edited my text accordingly.Regarding the function pointer: [6.3.2.3§8](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p8) actually covers that already. Oh, wait, I just noticed what you mean. Edited.