# Calculate member offset of unknown type

Tags: c++, struct, offsetof

I want to get the offset of a struct's member. I know this has been asked multiple times and the answer is always the mighty **offsetof**. Well, my case is a little different: I need the offset of an unknown type. That is for example:

```
void fill_struct(void* unknown)
{
    ...
}
```

The only thing I will know from unknown is the order in which types are set. i.e.

```
int
int
float
...
string
```

And the main problem here is align/padding, since I don't know a way to calculate it nor if there is a way at all.

---

This kind of question is often replied with: *why would you want to do that?*

For those people: I'm implementing a JSON parser in C++, and faced a problem (representing multiple type arrays), and my solution is to map the array's values into a custom struct.

**I accept feedback regarding to that solution but I'm mainly interested in my question being answered**

Comment: You can start with a map of variants instead of guessing the layout.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious did not get your point... example?

Comment: You cannot calculate offsets from a void pointer in C, since it is a type of unknown size, as you say. Functions that accept a void pointer type must also take the size of the type it points to. `void*` is more usually used for a return argument. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/692564/concept-of-void-pointer-in-c-programming

Comment: Do not add C tag for C++ questions! This one might present a C++ specific solution. Although until now it is not clear what you want to accomplish. `void *` does not point to a structured object and both languages are statically typed, so you have to know the current type anyway.

Comment: @WeatherVane I understand that, but I'm able to cast it to char* and use pointer arithmetic. <- that works in some cases and others are flawed because of align/padding

Comment: Sound like some awful and unnecessary hack.

Comment: @Olaf Its C++, I'm just using void* for receiving any kind of pointers as parameters knowing its structure (but again, the problem is the align/padding)

Comment: @Olaf, I agree it's a hack... but nice stuff comes from hack... besides, this has academic purposes mostly.

Comment: Alignment is implementation specific. And some compilers have extensions to selectively disable padding per struct. So I don't see how it's possible to work out the field offsets based on just the info you have (field type and order). Unless you apply further constraints and assumptions on the system.

Comment: "but nice stuff comes from hack" as does the biggest crap and many of the security holes we are facing everywhere. I'd say the negative effects are the vast majority. And, sorry, but I'm not up to "academic" nonsense (i.e. without any gain in knowledge or practical use). Good luck with further "research".

Comment: @AlanAu: I do not understand the problem. If he has the field-types and order, he also has a proper struct definition he can cast to. If that is serialized data, there is already a message layout description he can deserialize into a proper struct (hmm, .. XY-problem?).

Comment: @Olaf sorry to hurt you so deeply

Comment: @Olaf I could not have access to the struct definitions since they would be custom (user defined), as this is intended to be a library

Comment: Rodolfo: so a few things come to mind. why are you trying to use a struct to represent array types? why wouldn't you use either a C union type, or a C++ variant type like boost::variant to represent "general" json types? and use a std::vector to represent a json array? besides this, why don't you use any of the many wondeful existing C++ json reading/writing libraries? i can personally vouch for this one from the makers of boost::spirit https://github.com/cierelabs/json_spirit

Comment: @Olaf I might have misunderstood OP requirements but my reading is that OP is trying to serialise an unknown struct type. The field types and ordering is known. But the alignment is not known. So two structs can have exactly the same fields in the same order but packing may have been enabled on one of the structs and not the other. In which case the offsets will be different despite their same field types and ordering.

Comment: @AlanAu: But that would require a completely different approach (that's why is more and more smell an XY-problem). To serialize JSON, one uses a generic struct per JSON-element which can basically hold the few different JSON types and links to the next. In C++ one can use classes or a struct with union and type-tag similar to C. I completely agree with your concerns in general, but I do not see how this is really related to parsing JSON. You just build your object -tree while parsin, each node one JSON-value/subtree. How could you provide dynamic types in C++ otherwise?

Comment: @ChrisBeck: I have never seen boost::variant, will keep that in mind. I cannot use std::vector for JSON arrays since they can have multiple types. And why am I not using a third-party library? because I want to implement a technique that claims to be the best http://www.infoq.com/articles/HIgh-Performance-Parsers-in-Java-V2 (but in c++)

Comment: Rodolfo: boost::variant is the most natural way in C++ to represent what are sometimes called "algebraic union types", i.e. a data that is of exactly one of the types in the union. and it does this without causing memory or allocation problems, it is a fully-stack allocated object. you can use a std::vector of boost::variant for json arrays, even though they are heterogenous, and then you won't have to do any alignment or padding calculations. in modern C++ you generally never have to do that, it's a high-level programming language. even in C you usually don't have to do that.

Comment: Use templates instead of ugly `void*` functions and then you can just use `offsetof`

Comment: @Olaf: It might be an XY problem, but I was curious about align/padding calculation as priority. I know there are plenty of solutions to my problem, I just wanted an intuitive way to represent JSON within C++

Comment: void* is rarely the intuitive solution in C++

Comment: @ChrisBeck: I suspect OP wants to build true C++ structs dynamically at run-time from the JSON. That would work in Python, but not in C++.

Comment: I mean he could just use std::map or similar for each node of the json. That's basically what the python solution is also? Python doesn't have true structs at all

Comment: @Olaf: I think it can be done with meta-programming, and it would not be runtime

Comment: @RodolfoCastilloMateluna: No offence, but you seem to have quite some missconceptions. Perhaps you should read about the difference between [statically and dynamically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statically_typed#Type_checking) typed languages.

Comment: @ChrisBeck: Python is completely  object-oriented, much further than C++ or Java. you can easily have a simple struct-like container class. That would be run-time expandable/modifyable (Python is strong dynamically typed).

Comment: Olaf: but it will not be allocated contiguously like a C / C++ struct, it will be heap allocated similar to a std::map or std::unordered_map. and lookup will be much harder than adding a fixed offset to a pointer, you'll have to traverse the data structure at runtime.

Comment: @RodolfoCastilloMateluna: Is the JSON parsed at compiler-time or run-time?

Comment: @Olaf: Not offended, I do know what are statically/dynamically typed languages... I insist, if I generated code from a user's struct definition, so I can get its offset with **offsetof**, it would be at compile-time, and the types would be well-defined

Comment: @ChrisBeck: No. Python's most important type is likely maps/dicts. IIRC, the JSON module uses also dicts to store the entries - of course: `name: value`. That's why I do not get what OP actually wants. I did not say it is fast, flexibility always comes at the cost of overhead.

Comment: Rodolfo: if thats how you want to do it, then maybe you should look into boost::fusion? boost::fusion is a very powerful library that allows you to do things like, iterate over the sequence of members of a struct, which you can't do normally in the language. it is based on template meta programming. it's one of the easier of those kinds of libraries to use imo

Comment: @Olaf: the JSON would be parsed at run-time, but I expect the user to know the way its arranged, so at compile-time I would already have user-defined array layouts

Comment: @ChrisBeck: I will take a look at that (I was never atracted to boost black magic, guess I have to give up some day)

Comment: @RodolfoCastilloMateluna: But if you have the layouts already, you also have the structs. The JSON as a pure text-serialization has no specific binary layout anyway. Ok, I'm off, need some sleep. Have fun!

Comment: @Olaf: This is a total mess... good chat anyways haha

Comment: Yes. As I suspected: XY-problem. Perhaps you take the information you got and think over it first. The pointers from @ChrisBeck sound promising.

Comment: Rodolfo: I've always been more attracted to the boost black magic than the `void *` `offsetof` black magic. You pick your poison I suppose :D

Comment: @ChrisBeck: Suppose I was always attracted to good ol' hacks